# What are the use(s) for struct tags in Go?

Tags: go, struct, reflection, tags

In the [Go Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), it mentions a brief overview of tags:

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal tag,
>   which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding
>   field declaration. The tags are made visible through a reflection
>   interface but are otherwise ignored.
>
> ```
> // A struct corresponding to the TimeStamp protocol buffer.
> // The tag strings define the protocol buffer field numbers.
> struct {
>   microsec  uint64 "field 1"
>   serverIP6 uint64 "field 2"
>   process   string "field 3"
> }
> ```

This is a very short explanation IMO, and I was wondering if anyone could provide me with what use these tags would be?

Comment: I have a related question for uses of 'semantic' comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53101458/what-are-the-syntactic-and-semantic-rules-for-meaningful-comments-in-go

Comment: Correction that link should be https://stackoverflow.com/q/53487371/1569204

Answer (score 1034, accepted):

A tag for a field allows you to attach meta-information to the field which can be acquired using reflection. Usually it is used to provide transformation info on how a struct field is encoded to or decoded from another format (or stored/retrieved from a database), but you can use it to store whatever meta-info you want to, either intended for another package or for your own use.

As mentioned in the documentation of [`reflect.StructTag`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag), by convention the value of a tag string is a space-separated list of `key:"value"` pairs, for example:

```
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name" xml:"name"`
}
```

The `key` usually denotes the package that the subsequent `"value"` is for, for example `json` keys are processed/used by the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package.

If multiple information is to be passed in the `"value"`, usually it is specified by separating it with a comma (`','`), e.g.

```
Name string `json:"name,omitempty" xml:"name"`
```

Usually a dash value (`'-'`) for the `"value"` means to exclude the field from the process (e.g. in case of `json` it means not to marshal or unmarshal that field).

#### Example of accessing your custom tags using reflection

We can use reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package) to access the tag values of struct fields. Basically we need to acquire the [`Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) of our struct, and then we can query fields e.g. with `Type.Field(i int)` or `Type.FieldByName(name string)`. These methods return a value of [`StructField`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField) which describes / represents a struct field; and `StructField.Tag` is a value of type [`StructTag`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) which describes / represents a tag value.

Previously we talked about *"convention"*. This convention means that if you follow it, you may use the [`StructTag.Get(key string)`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Get) method which parses the value of a tag and returns you the `"value"` of the `key` you specify. The *convention* is implemented / built into this `Get()` method. If you don't follow the convention, `Get()` will not be able to parse `key:"value"` pairs and find what you're looking for. That's also not a problem, but then you need to implement your own parsing logic.

Also there is [`StructTag.Lookup()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Lookup) (was added in Go 1.7) which is *"like `Get()` but distinguishes the tag not containing the given key from the tag associating an empty string with the given key"*.

So let's see a simple example:

```
type User struct {
    Name  string `mytag:"MyName"`
    Email string `mytag:"MyEmail"`
}

u := User{"Bob", "bob@mycompany.com"}
t := reflect.TypeOf(u)

for _, fieldName := range []string{"Name", "Email"} {
    field, found := t.FieldByName(fieldName)
    if !found {
        continue
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nField: User.%s\n", fieldName)
    fmt.Printf("\tWhole tag value : %q\n", field.Tag)
    fmt.Printf("\tValue of 'mytag': %q\n", field.Tag.Get("mytag"))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Al_m3GYl5j)):

```
Field: User.Name
    Whole tag value : "mytag:\"MyName\""
    Value of 'mytag': "MyName"

Field: User.Email
    Whole tag value : "mytag:\"MyEmail\""
    Value of 'mytag': "MyEmail"
```

---

GopherCon 2015 had a presentation about struct tags called:

**[The Many Faces of Struct Tags (slide)](https://github.com/gophercon/2015-talks/blob/master/Sam%20Helman%20%26%20Kyle%20Erf%20-%20The%20Many%20Faces%20of%20Struct%20Tags/StructTags.pdf)** (and a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SCRvMunkdA))

#### Here is a list of commonly used tag keys:

- `json`      - used by the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package, detailed at [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)
- `xml`       - used by the [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) package, detailed at [`xml.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal)
- `bson`      - used by [gobson](https://labix.org/gobson), detailed at [`bson.Marshal()`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Marshal); also by the [mongo-go](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) driver, detailed at [bson package doc](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#hdr-Structs)
- `protobuf`  - used by [`github.com/golang/protobuf/proto`](http://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto), detailed in the package doc
- `yaml`      - used by the [`gopkg.in/yaml.v2`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2) package, detailed at [`yaml.Marshal()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal)
- `db`        - used by the [`github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) package; also used by [`github.com/go-gorp/gorp`](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp) package
- `orm`       - used by the [`github.com/astaxie/beego/orm`](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/orm) package, detailed at [Models – Beego ORM](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/overview.md)
- `gorm`      - used by [`gorm.io/gorm`](https://gorm.io/), examples can be found in their [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/)
- `valid`     - used by the [`github.com/asaskevich/govalidator`](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator) package, examples can be found in the project page
- `datastore` - used by [`appengine/datastore`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference) (Google App Engine platform, Datastore service), detailed at [Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-Properties)
- `schema`    - used by [`github.com/gorilla/schema`](http://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/schema) to fill a `struct` with HTML form values, detailed in the package doc
- `asn1`      - used by the [`encoding/asn1`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/) package, detailed at [`asn1.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/#Marshal) and [`asn1.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/#Unmarshal)
- `csv`       - used by the [`github.com/gocarina/gocsv`](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv) package
- `env`       - used by the [`github.com/caarlos0/env`](https://github.com/caarlos0/env) package

Answer (score 170):

Here is a really simple example of tags being used with the [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to control how fields are interpreted during encoding and decoding:

Try live: http://play.golang.org/p/BMeR8p1cKf

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Person struct {
    FirstName  string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName   string `json:"last_name"`
    MiddleName string `json:"middle_name,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    json_string := `
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    }`

    person := new(Person)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(json_string), person)
    fmt.Println(person)

    new_json, _ := json.Marshal(person)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", new_json)
}

// *Output*
// &{John Smith }
// {"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}
```

The json package can look at the tags for the field and be told how to map json <=> struct field, and also extra options like whether it should ignore empty fields when serializing back to json.

Basically, any package can use reflection on the fields to look at tag values and act on those values. There is a little more info about them in the reflect package
http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag :

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally
>   space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string
>   consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '),
>   quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using
>   U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

Comment: Kind of like Java annotations?

Comment: @isbadawi: I'm not a java guy, but at quick glance of the definition of java annotations, yes it seems they are achieving the same goal; attaching metadata to elements that can be examined at runtime.

Comment: Not really java annotations. Java annotations are type safe and compile time checked - not string literals like go. Java annotations are much more powerful and robust than golang basic metadata provisions.

Comment: As part of the MongoDB driver for Go, mgo, also uses tags in its bson package (which can also be used by itself). It gives you precise control over what BSON is generated. See http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#pkg-files

Comment: Are there other examples besides JSON and BSON?

Comment: This flag parsing package that I like to use makes use of struct tags for defining your flag options: http://godoc.org/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags

Comment: Sounds like since it's available at reflection time (runtime) any programmer can read the values and be creative in utilizing them. Python `@tags` are similar, allowing for runtime injection and interpretation. The cool thing about python though is you can subclass the tags, if I recall

Comment: Sounds like the equivalent of `[Attributes]` in C#.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I had a quick look at C# attributes. I would say they have similarities to go tags in that they provide runtime reflection info. However I would say C# attributes are more advanced since they can annotation more than just fields, such as classes and methods. And the attributes are actual classes with logic. C# is probably more similar to Python decorators. Go tags don't have any inherent logic. They can be introspected by something later at runtime that can derive meaning.

Answer (score 5):

It's some sort of specifications that specifies how packages treat with a field that is tagged.

for example:

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName string `json:"last_name"`
}
```

json tag informs `json` package that marshalled output of following user

```
u := User{
        FirstName: "some first name",
        LastName:  "some last name",
    }
```

would be like this:

```
{"first_name":"some first name","last_name":"some last name"}
```

other example is `gorm` package tags declares how database migrations must be done:

```
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name         string
  Age          sql.NullInt64
  Birthday     *time.Time
  Email        string  `gorm:"type:varchar(100);unique_index"`
  Role         string  `gorm:"size:255"` // set field size to 255
  MemberNumber *string `gorm:"unique;not null"` // set member number to unique and not null
  Num          int     `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT"` // set num to auto incrementable
  Address      string  `gorm:"index:addr"` // create index with name `addr` for address
  IgnoreMe     int     `gorm:"-"` // ignore this field
}
```

In this example for the field `Email` with gorm tag we declare that corresponding column in database for the field email must be of type varchar and 100 maximum length and it also must have unique index.

other example is `binding` tags that are used very mostly in `gin` package.

```
type Login struct {
    User     string `form:"user" json:"user" xml:"user"  binding:"required"`
    Password string `form:"password" json:"password" xml:"password" binding:"required"`
}


var json Login
if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&json); err != nil {
     c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
     return
}
```

the binding tag in this example gives hint to gin package that the data sent to API must have user and password fields cause these fields are tagged as required.

**So generraly tags are data that packages require to  know how should they treat with data of type different structs and best way to get familiar with the tags a package needs is READING A PACKAGE DOCUMENTATION COMPLETELY.**

Answer (score 0):

In Go, tags are essentially metadata associated with a struct field. They are defined as string literals that appear after the field name in a struct definition, and are enclosed in backticks or double quotes.

Tags serve several purposes in Go:

1. **Serialization and Deserialization**: One of the most common uses of tags is to aid in the serialization and deserialization of data. For example, when encoding a struct as JSON, the encoder will use the tag values to determine the JSON key names to use for each field.
2. **Reflection**: Go's reflection package allows programs to inspect and modify the structure of a program at runtime. Tags can be used to provide additional information about the fields of a struct that can be accessed via reflection.
3. **Validation**: Tags can be used to validate the data stored in a struct. For example, a tag could indicate that a particular field must be a valid email address, or that it must be a non-negative integer.
4. **Documentation**: Tags can be used to provide additional documentation about the fields of a struct. This can be useful for tools like godoc, which generate documentation for Go programs based on source code comments and other metadata.