# Strange type definition syntax in Golang (name, then type, then string literal)

Tags: go

I've been trying to find out how to use mgo (MongoDB driver for Go) and I came across this struct declaration:

```
type Something struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId "_id,omitempty"
    Name string
}
```

I don't quite understand the syntax of the first element (Id).  I understand that it's being declared as type `bson.ObjectId`, but what is the string literal doing there?

My question is not about the mgo driver functionality,
but about this strange `<name> <type> <string_literal>` syntax.

I couldn't find anything on the Go specs, and I don't know how to google this either.

Comment: See more info and examples here: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It's explained in the [Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) section of the [language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec):

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal
>   *tag*, which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration. The tags are made visible through a
>   [reflection interface](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) but are otherwise ignored.

```
// A struct corresponding to the TimeStamp protocol buffer.
// The tag strings define the protocol buffer field numbers.
struct {
    microsec  uint64 "field 1"
    serverIP6 uint64 "field 2"
    process   string "field 3"
}
```

Comment: specifically, in the case of mgo, the tag will set the key to be used when encoding the struct as bson.  This is also how the encoding/json package works.  Otherwise Go would use cap-initial keys.