# extra value in field in struct golang

Tags: go

What does this "extra" field `gorm:"primary_key"` do when creating a struct?

```
type Model struct {
    ID        uint `gorm:"primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) post for a general explanation. Leo Correa's answer gives the specific meaning for this particular tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tag used by the `gorm` package to let the package know that the field will be used as a primary key

See https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/b9a39be9c5e77bb0bfebd516114a8a4d605c645a/model_struct.go#L135-L139

```
gormSettings := parseTagSetting(field.Tag.Get("gorm"))
if _, ok := gormSettings["PRIMARY_KEY"]; ok {
    field.IsPrimaryKey = true
    modelStruct.PrimaryFields = append(modelStruct.PrimaryFields, field)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are what I call 'annotations' they're used by various packages (in this case `gorm`) to provide more information about how to handle the type. Most commonly you see them on data transfer objects (like json and xml), both packages require them in most use cases.

In this case you're telling `gorm` this field is a primary key. From a cursory glance at that packages docs it is for relational modeling (like setting up types to map to an rmdb or something of that nature) so it makes sense here to see things like nullable, pk or fk.