# What is the usage of backtick in golang structs definition?

Tags: go

```
type NetworkInterface struct {
    Gateway              string `json:"gateway"`
    IPAddress            string `json:"ip"`
    IPPrefixLen          int    `json:"ip_prefix_len"`
    MacAddress           string `json:"mac"`
    ...
}
```

I'm quite confused what's the function of contents in backtick, like `json:"gateway"`.

Is it just comment, like `//this is the gateway`?

Comment: JSON is of course prolific.  That the json library does not handle case conversion for the single most ubiquitous style (camel-case) both when serializing and deserializing, without this asinine hack, is really inexcusable.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can add extra meta information to Go structs in the form of tags. [Here are some examples of use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go).

In this case, the `json:"gateway"` is used by the [json package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) to encode the value of `Gateway` into the key `gateway` in the corresponding json object.

Example:

```
n := NetworkInterface{
   Gateway : "foo"
}
json.Marshal(n)
// will output `{"gateway":"foo",...}`
```

Answer (score 154):

The content inside the backticks are [tags](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal tag,
> which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding
> field declaration. The tags are made visible through a reflection
> interface and take part in type identity for structs but are otherwise
> ignored.
>
> ```
> // A struct corresponding to the TimeStamp protocol buffer.
> // The tag strings define the protocol buffer field numbers.
> struct {
>   microsec  uint64 "field 1"
>   serverIP6 uint64 "field 2"
>   process   string "field 3"
> }
> ```

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) for a more detailed explanation and answer.

The [back quotes](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) are used to create raw string literals which can contain any type of character:

> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes ``.
> Within the quotes, any character is legal except back quote.