# Go json.Unmarshal key with \u0000 \x00

Tags: json, string, go, unmarshalling

Here is the Go [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/l37vSRjIhn) link.

Basically there are some special characters (`'\u0000'`) in my JSON string key:

```
var j = []byte(`{"Page":1,"Fruits":["5","6"],"\u0000*\u0000_errorMessages":{"x":"123"},"*_successMessages":{"ok":"hi"}}`)
```

I want to Unmarshal it into a struct:

```
type Response1 struct {
    Page   int
    Fruits []string
    Msg    interface{} `json:"*_errorMessages"`
    Msg1   interface{} `json:"\\u0000*\\u0000_errorMessages"`
    Msg2   interface{} `json:"\u0000*\u0000_errorMessages"`
    Msg3   interface{} `json:"\0*\0_errorMessages"`
    Msg4   interface{} `json:"\\0*\\0_errorMessages"`
    Msg5   interface{} `json:"\x00*\x00_errorMessages"`
    Msg6   interface{} `json:"\\x00*\\x00_errorMessages"`
    SMsg   interface{} `json:"*_successMessages"`
}
```

I tried a lot but it's not working. 
This link might help [golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode_test.go](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode_test.go).

Comment: I had a similar issue noticing afterwards that my document was encoded using UTF-16.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** With the current [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) implementation it is not possible using only [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373).

**Note:** It's an *implementation* restriction, not a *specification* restriction. (It's the restriction of the `json` package implementation, not the restriction of the [struct tags specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types).)

---

Some background: you specified your tags with a [raw string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals):

> The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes...

So no unescaping or unquoting happens in the content of the raw string literal *by the compiler*.

The convention for struct tag values quoted from [`reflect.StructTag`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag):

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

What this means is that by convention tag values are a list of (key:"value") pairs separated by spaces. There are quite a few restrictions for keys, but values may be anything, and values (should) use "Go string literal syntax", this means that these **values will be unquoted at runtime from code** (by a call to [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote), called [`from StructTag.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Get), in source file [`reflect/type.go`](https://golang.org/src/reflect/type.go), currently line #809).

So no need for double quoting. See your simplified example:

```
type Response1 struct {
    Page   int
    Fruits []string
    Msg    interface{} `json:"\u0000_abc"`
}
```

Now the following code:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(Response1{})
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", t.Field(2).Tag)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", t.Field(2).Tag.Get("json"))
```

Prints:

```
"json:\"\\u0000_abc\""
"\x00_abc"
```

As you can see, the value part for the `json` key is `"\x00_abc"` so it properly contains the zero character.

**But how will the `json` package use this?**

The `json` package uses the value returned by [`StructTag.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Get) (from the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package), exactly what we did. You can see it in the [`json/encode.go`](http://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go) source file, `typeFields()` function, currently line #1032. So far so good.

Then it calls the unexported `json.parseTag()` function, in [`json/tags.go`](http://golang.org/src/encoding/json/tags.go) source file, currently line #17. This cuts the part after the comma (which becomes the "tag options").

And finally `json.isValidTag()` function is called with the previous value, in source file [`json/encode.go`](http://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go), currently line #731. This function checks the runes of the passed `string`, and (besides a set of pre-defined allowed characters `"!#$%&()*+-./:<=>?@[]^_{|}~ "`) rejects everything that is not a unicode letter or digit (as defined by [`unicode.IsLetter()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsLetter) and [`unicode.IsDigit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsDigit)):

```
if !unicode.IsLetter(c) && !unicode.IsDigit(c) {
    return false
}
```

`'\u0000'` is not part of the pre-defined allowed characters, and as you can guess now, it is neither a letter nor a digit:

```
// Following code prints "INVALID":
c := '\u0000'
if !unicode.IsLetter(c) && !unicode.IsDigit(c) {
    fmt.Println("INVALID")
}
```

And since `isValidTag()` returns `false`, the `name` (which is the value for the `json` key, without the "tag options" part) will be discarded (`name = ""`) and not used. So no match will be found for the struct field containing a unicode zero.

For an alternative solution use a `map`, or a custom [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) or use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage).

But I would highly discourage using such ugly json keys. I understand likely you are just trying to parse such json response and it may be out of your reach, but you should fight against using these keys as they will just cause more problems later on (e.g. if stored in db, by inspecting records it will be very hard to spot that there are `'\u0000'` characters in them as they may be displayed as nothing).

Comment: Brilliant investigation!

Comment: Now I am just filtering out the key and fighting against the ugly keys as you said. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do in such way due to: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types

But You can unmarshal to `map[string]interface{}` then check field names of that object through [regexp](http://godoc.org/regexp).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with struct tags. The best thing you can do is unmarshal it into `map[string]interface{}` and then get the values manually:

```
var b = []byte(`{"\u0000abc":42}`)
var m map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(m, m["\x00abc"])
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/RtS7Nst0d7.