# How can I add a new boolean property to a Golang struct and set the default value to true?

Tags: go, struct, datastore

I have a user struct that corresponds to an entity. How can I add a new property `active` and set the default value to `true`?

Can I also set the value of that property to `true` for all existing entities by some easy method?

```
type User struct {
    Id              int64     `json:"id"`
    Name            string    `json:"name"`
}
```

Bonus questions: I don't quite understand the syntax in the struct. What do the three columns represent? What do the JSON strings have ``around them?

Comment: About the `json:"name"` thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go

Answer (score 2):

```
//You can't change declared type.
type User struct {
    Id              int64     `json:"id"`
    Name            string    `json:"name"`
}
//Instead you construct a new one embedding existent
type ActiveUser struct {
    User
    Active bool
}
//you instantiate type literally
user := User{1, "John"}
//and you can provide constructor for your type
func MakeUserActive(u User) ActiveUser {
    auser := ActiveUser{u, true}
    return auser
}
activeuser := MakeUserActive(user)
```

You can see it works https://play.golang.org/p/UU7RAn5RVK

Comment: I think more idiomatic would be `NewUser`, with `Active` set to true when this is the default value and provide a `Deactivate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the default value as true at the moment when you are passing the struct type to a variable, but this means you need to extend that struct with a  new `Active` field.

```
type User struct {
    Id              int64     `json:"id"`
    Name            string    `json:"name"`
    Active          bool
}

user := User{1, "John", true}
```

`json:"id"` means that you are mapping the json decoded object field to the field `id` in your struct type. Practically you are deserialize the json string into object fields which later you can map to their specific field inside the struct.