# Reading data from Google Could Datastore on AppEngine with Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Here is a screen shot of the entities I'm trying to read.

[Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYMWK.png)

Here is my go code:

```
package readfromgcd

import (
        "net/http"
        "appengine"
        "appengine/datastore"
        "fmt"
)

type person struct {
    firstname string
    lastname string
}

func init () {
    http.HandleFunc("/", readpeople)
}

func readpeople (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    q := datastore.NewQuery("person")
    people := make([]person, 0, 20)
    if _, err := q.GetAll(c, &people); err !=nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello world!")
}
```

I get the following result:
datastore: cannot load field "firstName" into a "readpeople.person": no such struct field

Here is a screenshot.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VODFo.png)

This code does not show doing anything with this data.  I wanted to limit this post to the retrieval.  I must be missing something simple.  Where have I gone wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property names in your datastore do not match field names in your Go struct `person`. For example in your datastore `person` has property `firstName` but your struct has field `firstname`.

So first thing is to make them match; or if you want to use different names in your Go struct, use [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) to define the mappings.

Another important thing: you have to export your type and its fields in order so that the `datastore` package will be able to load data into it using reflection. So you have to start your type name and its fields with uppercase letters:

```
type Person struct {
    FirstName string `datastore:"firstName"`
    LastName string  `datastore:"lastName"`
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I made this change, and it worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: I cleaned up this code and added some code to write data back and display the data as well.  I've uploaded all of if on GitHub as a sample app.  Perhaps this will be useful to someone in the future. [link](https://github.com/wdwinslow/go-appengine-cloud-datastore)