# datastore: invalid entity type on Put

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to create a wrapper around my Kinds and here is how I am doing it:

```
package model

import (
    "time"
)

type Kind interface {
    Name() string
}

type Message struct {
    Text      string
    CreatedOn time.Time
    UserId    string
}

func (q Message) Name() string {
    return "MESSAGE"
}
```

And the reason I introduced `type Kind interface` is:

```
// Stores the given model for the the kind in data store
func Store(req *http.Request, data Kind) error {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)
    key := datastore.NewKey(ctx, data.Name(), "", 0, nil)
    _, err := datastore.Put(ctx, key, &data)
    return err
}
```

As you can see, I am using `data.Name()` to get the kinds name.

When I try to save the data, it complains about:

```
datastore: invalid entity type
```

I read that this could be due to not passing the reference to `datastore.Put`, but I am doing that. Any idea?

I must add that when I checked the type of data (using `reflect.TypeOf()`), it is `model.Message` which is correct too. So it is a concrete type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`datastore.Put()`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore#Put) expects the entity data as a struct pointer or any value that implements [`PropertyLoadSaver`](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/datastore#PropertyLoadSaver). This is clearly stated in its doc:

> `src` must be a struct pointer or implement `PropertyLoadSaver`

What you pass to `datastore.Put()` is a pointer value, a pointer to an interface. It's true that the value stored in the interface is of concrete type `model.Message`, but they are not the same.

You can't use `reflect.TypeOf().String()` because in case of interface it tells you the concrete type stored in the interface (so it might be misleading).

See this code to demonstrate the difference:

```
var data Kind = Message{}
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&data).Kind())
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&data).Elem().Kind())

var msg Message = Message{}
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&msg).Kind())
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(&msg).Elem().Kind())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dYi3ACTvBT)):

```
ptr
interface
ptr
struct
```

All in all, `&data` is a pointer to an interface, and that is not allowed to be passed to `datastore.Put()`. You can only pass `*Message`, or if you want to pass an interface value (NOT a pointer to an interface), then make sure to implement `PropertyLoadSaver`.

Comment: thanks for well explained answer to my confusion about the concrete type. I am trying to understand how implementing the `PropertyLoadSaver` (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#hdr-The_PropertyLoadSaver_Interface) can help me in this situation. What I would like to achieve here is to make a generic function which can store any Kind and it can get the kind's name using the metadata attached to the kind itself. I tried to achieve that by introducing `Name()`. Do you have any solution to this? So the caller doesn't need to specify the kind name all the time.

Comment: @MaxZooZoo `Name()` is a too generic method name, I would choose something more specific (e.g. `EntityName()`). But I would not go this down this path, entity name is rather a meta-info and not something a concrete implementation should decide. Better would be to add a new field to structs, using [struct tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to exclude it, but the tag value could hold the info for entity name. Or even better option would be to build a registry of names, a `map[Type]string` mapping from Go type to entity name.

Comment: That's exactly my point. I liked the tag approach, but I was wondering if there is a way to tag a struct itself since the metadata is to be linked to the whole struct instead of a specific field in the struct. If you are familiar with annotations in Java, it would be a class annotation. Do we have such a thing in Go?

Comment: @MaxZooZoo No, only fields can be "tagged". To "tag" types, use a registry mentioned above: `map[Type]string`.