# Static member of a struct in Golang

Tags: go

Say I have a struct:

```
type DriverData struct {
    TypePath string = "Foo.Bar.DriverData"
}
```

I want to be able to reference `TypePath` without having to create an instance of the struct, something like:

```
typePath := DriverData.TypePath
```

but that's not possible in Golang.

So I was wondering - maybe there is a way to create a map, and associate the type with a string, something like:

```
type DriverData struct {

}

type PilotData struct {

}

type BoatmasterData struct {

}

typeMap := map[struct]string{
   DriverData: "Foo.Bar.DriverData",
   PilotData:   "Foo.Bar.PilotData",
   BoatmasterData: "Foo.Bar.BoatmasterData",
}
```

**Question:**

Is this the best approach to create static properties on a struct? Storing the static properties in a map like this?

Comment: What do you really want to do?

Comment: I want to store a string on a struct, static member, and make it hardcoded. So that struct is tagged with a string. Makes sense right? Metaprogramming stuff here.

Comment: The ultimate goal is so that I can have a string on a struct, which represents the path to the struct in the codebase.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do dynamically typed programming with `Golang`. I doubt it's meant for that, but reflection might help. Not quite sure what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: @ishaan no, not trying to do dynamically typed anything, I am just trying to store a static member on a struct. This seems to be a desired feature for metaprogramming, as you see here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7112

Comment: Ahh, so something similar to static in say Java. Well, i've never done anything like this in my go code, only have initialised singleton structs with values on init, mostly from a JSON string :(  I do wish there was something like this, so I wouldn't have to. Would be a lot of help in base configs across the code base.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you might like this example https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#example_StructTag

Comment: @Vorsprung that might work, only problem I might foresee is if the struct has more fields and I don't currently have the data to populate the other fields on hand.

Comment: @Vorsprung I tried out the StructTag idea and that seems to work, if you can add an answer showing how you unmarshal JSON with a StructTag and how certain fields might be ignored if they don't have the `json` struct tag?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510763/go-static-member-variable-such-as-oop-langage) what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, I don't think you can store a struct in a map like that, maybe only an instance of the struct?

Comment: Would putting that value as a package-level constant, outside but next to the struct, meet your needs?

Comment: @DavidMaze which value as a package-level constant?

Comment: `const TypePath string = "..."`, at the top level of some source file, outside of the struct definition.

Answer (score 3):

You can define methods to give you those values:

```
type DriverData struct {
}

func (DriverData) Path() string {
    return "Foo.Bar.DriverData"
}

type PilotData struct {
}

func (PilotData) Path() string {
    return "Foo.Bar.PilotData"
}

type BoatmasterData struct {
}

func (BoatmasterData) Path() string {
    return "Foo.Bar.BoatmasterData"
}
```

Does that do what you want?

See https://play.golang.org/p/zR7RZwMVEdf.

Comment: it is not static member. anyway you declared object