# What does mean about the `json:"make"` at the end of Make string in Golang?

Tags: go

I am working on some Golang source code, and confusing on Program syntax as below.
What does mean about the `json:"make"` at the end of Make string in Golang?

```
type Vehicle struct {
    Make            string `json:"make"`
    Model           string `json:"model"`
    Reg             string `json:"reg"`
    VIN             int    `json:"VIN"`                 
    Owner           string `json:"owner"`
    Scrapped        bool   `json:"scrapped"`
    Status          int    `json:"status"`
    Colour          string `json:"colour"`
    V5cID           string `json:"v5cID"`
    LeaseContractID string `json:"leaseContractID"`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags are used by encoding packages like `encoding/json` or `encoding/xml` to control how fields are interpreted during encoding and decoding. Uses of tags are already discussed in this thread: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go)