# Unmarshal array from xml in go language

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

Trying to parse xml containing an array using `encoding/xml` package

[Link to code here](https://play.golang.org/p/lcYXQ_cBTX)

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)
var data = `
<Patient>
          <Name>
                <LastName>Biscayne</LastName>
                <FirstName>Sophia</FirstName>
            </Name>
            <Gender>F</Gender>
            <CommunicationNumbers>
                <Communication>
                    <Number>9415551223</Number>
                    <Qualifier>TE</Qualifier>
                </Communication>
    <Communication>
                    <Number>4055559999</Number>
                    <Qualifier>TE</Qualifier>
                </Communication>
            </CommunicationNumbers>
        </Patient>
`
type Name struct {
    LastName string
    FirstName string
}

type Communication struct {
    Number string `xml:Number`
    Qualifier string `xml:Qualifier`
}

type Patient struct {
    Name Name
    Gender string
    CommunicationNumbers []Communication `xml:CommunicationNumbers>Communication`
}

func main() {

    patient := Patient{}
    _ = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &patient)   

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", patient)
}
```

I am not able to get communication numbers. The output is as follows:

> main.Patient{Name:main.Name{LastName:"Biscayne", FirstName:"Sophia"}, Gender:"F", CommunicationNumbers:[]main.Communication{main.Communication{Number:"", Qualifier:""}}}

Answer (score 3):

Fix is really easy: you have to put the path in quotes:

```
CommunicationNumbers []Communication `xml:"CommunicationNumbers>Communication"`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d7vVd8fyZa)):

> main.Patient{Name:main.Name{LastName:"Biscayne", FirstName:"Sophia"}, Gender:"F", CommunicationNumbers:[]main.Communication{main.Communication{Number:"9415551223", Qualifier:"TE"}, main.Communication{Number:"4055559999", Qualifier:"TE"}}}

In fact you always have to put it in quotes, even if it is not a path but just an XML tag name:

```
type Communication struct {
    Number    string `xml:"Number"`
    Qualifier string `xml:"Qualifier"`
}
```

As mentioned in the documentation of [`reflect.StructTag`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag), by convention the value of a tag string is a space-separated `key:"value"` pairs. The `encoding/xml` package uses this convention by using the [`StructTag.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Get) method. If you omit the quotes, the name you specify in the tag will not be used (but the name of the field will be used).

Read more about struct tags here: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)