# golang json serialization/deserialization of recursive data model

Tags: json, serialization, go

Lets say I have:

```
type IObject interface {
}

type Item struct {
    Description string
    Data        []byte
}

type FunctionX1 struct {
    Object IInclusionObject
}

type FunctionX2 struct {
    Object1 IInclusionObject
    Object2 IInclusionObject
}
```

I would like to be able to serialization/deserialization a model, where `Item`, `FunctionX1` `FunctionX2` they all implement `IObject` and they could be pointing to each other arbitrarily deep.

Note that I do not want: `FunctionX1{Item{"foo", []byte("bar")}}` to be serialized as:

```
"object": {
    "Description": "foo"
    "Data": ...
}
```

but rather:

```
"FunctionX1": {
    "item": { 
        "Description": "foo"
        "Data": ...
    }
}
```

Do I need to do my own JSON marshaller - it does not seem that I can use the existing one.

Related questions in case I need my own. Is there JSON prettifier where I can stream valid but randomly formatted JSON and it to output pretty version (note the JSON could be significantly large - I do not want to generate, parse generate formatted).

Answer (score 2):

### With Wrappers (struct or map)

You may use [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to map fields of structs to different names in/from JSON. So with this you can change `"Object"` to `"item"`:

```
type FunctionX1 struct {
    Object IInclusionObject `json:"item"`
}
```

But you still need a wrapper struct or map if you want `"FunctionX1"` to appear in the JSON text. For example:

```
f := FunctionX1{Item{"foo", []byte("bar")}}

if data, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"FunctionX1": f}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Output:

```
{"FunctionX1":{"item":{"Description":"foo","Data":"YmFy"}}}
```

Or with a wrapper struct:

```
type Wrapper struct {
    FunctionX1 FunctionX1
}

f := FunctionX1{Item{"foo", []byte("bar")}}

if data, err := json.Marshal(Wrapper{f}); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Output is the same:

```
{"FunctionX1":{"item":{"Description":"foo","Data":"YmFy"}}}
```

If you want pretty formatted JSON, you may use [`json.MarshalIndent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent) to do the marshaling:

```
if data, err := json.MarshalIndent(Wrapper{f}, "", "  "); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "FunctionX1": {
    "item": {
      "Description": "foo",
      "Data": "YmFy"
    }
  }
}
```

Try all the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Q_RPFI82IT).

### With Custom Marshaling

If you don't want to utilize a wrapper struct or map, you need to use custom marshalling, but it's quite simple:

```
type FunctionX1 struct {
    Object IInclusionObject `json:"item"`
}

func (f FunctionX1) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type FunctionX1_ FunctionX1
    return json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"FunctionX1": FunctionX1_(f)})
}
```

Effectively we moved the wrapping into the `MarshalJSON()` method, so others marshaling values of `FunctionX1` don't have to.

Testing it:

```
f := FunctionX1{Item{"foo", []byte("bar")}}

if data, err := json.Marshal(f); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}

if data, err := json.MarshalIndent(f, "", "  "); err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Note that the new `FunctionX1_` type inside `MarshalJSON()` is to avoid infinite "recursion".

Output:

```
{"FunctionX1":{"item":{"Description":"foo","Data":"YmFy"}}}
{
  "FunctionX1": {
    "item": {
      "Description": "foo",
      "Data": "YmFy"
    }
  }
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wZNAp8dcb5).

Comment: Thanks, @icza. Custom marshaling seems very close to what I want, with one exception.The object that is an argument to FinctionX1 might not be an item but another FunctionX1 or FunctionX2 in which case the sub-item should not be called item. I tried to apply the same custom marshaler to item too, but I am getting one extra level there: https://play.golang.org/p/Op2tg1LOtZ. Ideas how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out https://play.golang.org/p/6lVxnjnyit