# AppEngine Datastore: byte slice vs datastore.ByteString

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I require a property with a short sequence of bytes but I don't need an index on the property. The `datastore.ByteString` property type is meant for short sequences of bytes and is indexed whereas the normal `[]byte` property is meant for longer sequences of bytes and is *not* indexed.

I'm compelled to use `[]byte` because I don't need the index and it'll save me the extra write-cost but is it better that I use `datastore.ByteString` because it's meant for short values? Are there any benefits to doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type [`datastore.ByteString`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#ByteString) is really just a regular `[]byte` slice, see its declaration:

```
type ByteString []byte
```

The difference is that if you have a property of type `ByteString`, AppEngine will try to index it by default. Since datastore index entires have limited length, the length of a `ByteString` value can only be max 1500 bytes to be indexable.

`ByteString` also doesn't have any additional methods which would add some benefit besides the indexability.

If you don't plan to index your property, simply use a `[]byte`. If you plan to index it because you want to search / filter by it, then you must use `ByteString`. This can be useful if for example you want to store hashes of some content (e.g. a file), and you want to search for a file based on its content hash. In this case a `ByteString` makes perfect sense and is most compact (compared to an alternative where you would store the hash as a `string` being the hexadecimal representation).

Note that even if you use `ByteString`, you can still make the property unindexed by using [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373), e.g.:

```
type MyEntity struct {
    Something datastore.ByteString `datastore:"something,noindex"`
}
```