# How to get all GET request query parameters into a structure in Go?

Tags: http, go, struct, query-string

Hi I want to transform get query parameters into a structure in Go, for example I have this structure:

```
type Filter struct {
    Offset int64  `json:"offset"`
    Limit  int64  `json:"limit"`
    SortBy string `json:"sortby"`
    Asc    bool   `json:"asc"`

    //User specific filters
    Username   string `json:"username"`
    First_Name string `json:"first_name"`
    Last_Name  string `json:"last_name"`
    Status     string `json:"status"`
}
```

And I have the optional parameters that the user can specify when sending a get request which are `Offset`, `Limit`, `SortBy`, `Asc`, `Username`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Status`.

If those parameters were sent in the body then I would do this:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {

    log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("Reading Body Message:failed:%v", err)

    return
}

var filter Filter
err = json.Unmarshal(b, &filter)
```

But I can't send body in a `GET` request so what is the solution instead of getting each parameter alone and then putting them into a structure?

Comment: That's the solution. Pick out each parameter from the request, assign it to the proper member of your struct.

Comment: @nos what if I have a lot of paraeters?

Comment: you should use the net/url package parse request deals with all of this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Using gorilla's `schema` package

The [`github.com/gorilla/schema`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/schema) package was invented exactly for this.

You can use [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to tell how to map URL parameters to struct fields, the `schema` package looks for the `"schema"` tag keys.

Using it:

```
import "github.com/gorilla/schema"

type Filter struct {
    Offset int64  `schema:"offset"`
    Limit  int64  `schema:"limit"`
    SortBy string `schema:"sortby"`
    Asc    bool   `schema:"asc"`

    //User specific filters
    Username   string `schema:"username"`
    First_Name string `schema:"first_name"`
    Last_Name  string `schema:"last_name"`
    Status     string `schema:"status"`
}

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }

    filter := new(Filter)
    if err := schema.NewDecoder().Decode(filter, r.Form); err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }

    // Do something with filter
    fmt.Printf("%+v", filter)
}
```

### Marshaling and unmarshaling using `json`

Note that the `schema` package will also try to convert parameter values to the type of the field.

If the struct would only contain fields of `[]string` type (or you're willing to make that compromise), you can do that without the `schema` package.

[`Request.Form`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) is a `map`, mapping from `string` to `[]string` (as one parameter may be listed multiple times in the URL:

```
Form url.Values
```

And [`url.Values`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values):

```
type Values map[string][]string
```

So for example if your `Filter` struct would look like this:

```
type Filter struct {
    Offset []string `json:"offset"`
    Limit  []string `json:"limit"`
    SortBy []string `json:"sortby"`
    // ..other fields
}
```

You could simply use the [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package to marshal `r.Form`, then unmarshal it into your struct:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }
    data, err := json.Marshal(r.Form)
    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }
    filter := new(Fiter)
    if err = json.Unmarshal(data, filter); err != nil {
        // Handle error
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", filter)
}
```

This solution handles if multiple values are provided for the same parameter name. If you don't care about multiple values and you just want one, you first have to "transform" `r.Form` to a `map` with single `string` values instead of `[]string`.

This is how it could look like:

```
type Filter struct {
    Offset string `json:"offset"`
    Limit  string `json:"limit"`
    SortBy string `json:"sortby"`
    // ..other fields
}

// Transformation from map[string][]string to map[string]string:
m := map[string]string{}
for k, v := range r.Form {
    m[k] = v[0]
}
```

And then you can marshal `m` and unmarshal into it into the `Filter` struct the same way.

Comment: Thank you, I am using your first solution but I am getting the default values of the elements inside Filter structure I am passing the parameters in the url query for example: localhost:8000/example?offset=1&limit=2
then I get the default values when printing filter

Comment: @user6638204 Sorry, that was a "typo", it should be `r.Form`. Fixed. Please try with that.

Comment: Even after all this time.. other approach if you are using echolab frameworks to server endpoints:

https://echo.labstack.com/guide/request

Comment: People who consider opting for gorilla/schema should note that the last commit on the repository is more than 1 year old and [gorilla project is looking for new maintainers](https://github.com/gorilla/schema/issues/187)

Answer (score 2):

### Using [ggicci/httpin](https://github.com/ggicci/httpin)

**Disclaimer**: I'm the creator and maintainer of this package.

**httpin** helps you easily decoding HTTP request data from

- **Query parameters**, e.g. `?name=john&is_member=true`
- **Headers**, e.g. `Authorization: xxx`
- **Form data**, e.g. `username=john&password=******`
- **JSON/XML Body**, e.g. `POST {"name":"john"}`
- **Path variables**, e.g. `/users/{username}`
- **File uploads**

#### How to use?

```golang
type ListUsersInput struct {
    Page     int  `in:"query=page"`
    PerPage  int  `in:"query=per_page"`
    IsMember bool `in:"query=is_member"`
}

func ListUsers(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    input := r.Context().Value(httpin.Input).(*ListUsersInput)

    if input.IsMember {
        // Do sth.
    }
    // Do sth.
}
```

**httpin** is:

- **well documented**: at https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/
- **well tested**: coverage over 98%
- **open integrated**: with [net/http](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/http), [go-chi/chi](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/gochi), [gorilla/mux](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/gorilla), [gin-gonic/gin](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/integrations/gin), etc.
- **extensible** (advanced feature): by adding your custom directives. Read [httpin - custom directives](https://ggicci.github.io/httpin/directives/custom) for more details.
- **awesome mentioned**: https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#forms

Comment: Nice and all, but I feel like you should provide an option to disable validation. The library should only be doing one thing: binding data. There are other robust validation libraries that can then take the resulting struct and apply various validation rules. Also, it does not seem to support "smart" URLS or paths (`/user/:user-id/ => /user/34`)

Answer (score 1):

For `Echo` framework, you can bind a query string to a structure like this sample code.

```
type Filter struct {
    Offset int64  `query:"offset"`
    Limit  int64  `query:"limit"`
    SortBy string `query:"sortby"`
    Asc    bool   `query:"asc"`

    //User specific filters
    Username   string `query:"username"`
    First_Name string `query:"first_name"`
    Last_Name  string `query:"last_name"`
    Status     string `query:"status"`
}

query := new(Filter)
if err := c.Bind(query); err != nil {
    // handle error here
}
```