# How to decode query parameter in golang

Tags: go, struct, gorilla

i have parameter

```
id_user
phone_number
```

I want to decode to my struct

```
type User struct{
     IDUser int `json:"id_user"`
     PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
}
```

is it possible to decode into struct? I use gorilla schema. My Code:

```
func User(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
  var decoder = schema.NewDecoder()
  var user User
  if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
  }

  err := decoder.Decode(&user, r.PostForm)
  if err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
  }
  respBody, err := json.Marshal(user)
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
  w.Write(respBody)
}
```

i input id_user = 1 and phone_number = qwerty. But the result is id_user = 0 and phone_number = "".

Comment: Decoding the body is not "query parameter". Get the logic and semantics straight, the rest will be easy.

Comment: Output what you actually receive here and all will probably become clear. You are probably just receiving the parameters in the wrong format (either as url params or otherwise encoded in body).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mentioned two fields are query params you can directly read it like this way:

```
func User(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
idUser := r.URL.Query().Get("id_user")
phoneNumber := r.URL.Query().Get("phone_number")
var user User
id, err := strconv.Atoi(idUser)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error converting string to int")
    return
}
user.IDUser = id
user.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber
respBody, _ := json.Marshal(user)
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
w.Write(respBody)
}
```

Otherwise you can directly pass the User struct in api payload and directly do the payLoad decoding like this

```
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user); err != nil {
      fmt.Println("error decoding api payload")
      return
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fix your tags from this:

```
type User struct{
    IDUser         int     `json:id_user`
    PhoneNumber    string  `json:phone_number`
}
```

to this:

```
type User struct{
    IDUser         int     `json:"id_user"`
    PhoneNumber    string  `json:"phone_number"`
}
```

So, you should use quotes in tag names.

Comment: haha thank you. oke i edit in my question. I already using tag names in my code..

Comment: if this answer is correct and works for you - please mark it as an "answer")

Comment: i already using tag names and it's not solve my problem.. in my question i forgot to add tag names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decode them directly into a structure without getting the values of the fields one by one then you can use `github.com/gorilla/schema`. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486740/how-to-get-all-get-request-query-parameters-into-a-structure-in-go).