# Equivalent of Request in Laravel with http.request in Go

Tags: laravel, go

I want to get the request "name" to format it before save it. In Laravel, it is easy to get the value with postman via `$request->input('name')` at the controller.

I learn Go recently and got confused how to get the same value from postman. I am using http/net in Go.

How do I get the `$request->input('name')` in Go as in Laravel?

I'm working with POST method.

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15407719/13860, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47748215/13860

Comment: Your comment works for GET method. I am using POST method. Doesn't work

Comment: It would be prudent to put these details in your question, so we aren't left guessing.  For a POST request, you need to parse the body first, by calling [ParseForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseForm), then use [FormValue](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.FormValue), for example.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()                     // Parses the request body
    name := r.Form.Get("name") // name will be "" if parameter is not set
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```