# XML parsing with Golang (abuse of entity attributes)

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I have an XML formatted like this, coming from a dump of a database

```
<table name="table1">
    <row>
        <col name="col1">value</col>
        <col name="col2">value</col>
        <col name="col3">value</col>
    </row>
   ...
</table>
<table name="table2">
    <row>
        <col name="col1">value</col>
        <col name="col2">value</col>
        <col name="col3">value</col>
        <col name="col4">value</col>
    </row>
   ...
</table>
```

I am trying to parse this in Go with `xml.Decode()` function but I can't handle such an XML. 
I tried to match some of the examples found googling XML parsing in Golang, but nothing suits this kind of format (with `name` attributes all over the entities).

*Update*

Thanks for the answers! What I'd like to achieve is: let's say I have a Table called "users" and a table called "categories", I'd like to create as many `User` and `Category` objects starting from that XML.
Based on your first answers I can easily use the `Table` objects parsed and then create my own objects, but I'd like to know if I can skip that and decode directly my objects instead.

Answer (score 2):

The doc of the [`xml.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) function describes how the mapping between XML documents and structs work (supplemented by doc of [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal)). If you're not familiar with struct tags, check out this answer: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

First you need to model the XML document. Note that if you don't have a wrapper XML element around all the others, that is not 1 XML document but multiple, such as your case. You have multiple `<table>` documents.

You can model them like this:

```
type Col struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Row struct {
    Cols []Col `xml:"col"`
}

type Table struct {
    Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Rows []Row  `xml:"row"`
}
```

And since you have multiple `<table>` elements, easiest is to create an [`xml.Decoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder) and parse each separately with a [`Decoder.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Decode) call (`Decoder.Decode()` will attempt to parse 1 XML document from its source reader).

This is how it can be done:

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))
for {
    var table Table
    if err := d.Decode(&table); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        break
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", table)
}
```

When there are no more data in the source `string`, `Decoder.Decode()` will report [`io.EOF`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#EOF). Running the above cod with the following `data` string:

```
const data = `<table name="table1">
    <row>
        <col name="col1">value1</col>
        <col name="col2">value2</col>
        <col name="col3">value3</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col name="col1">value4</col>
        <col name="col2">value5</col>
        <col name="col3">value6</col>
    </row>
</table>
<table name="table2">
    <row>
        <col name="col1">value7</col>
        <col name="col2">value8</col>
        <col name="col3">value9</col>
        <col name="col4">valueA</col>
    </row>
</table>`
```

The output is:

```
{Name:table1 Rows:[{Cols:[{Name:col1 Value:value1} {Name:col2 Value:value2} {Name:col3 Value:value3}]} {Cols:[{Name:col1 Value:value4} {Name:col2 Value:value5} {Name:col3 Value:value6}]}]}
{Name:table2 Rows:[{Cols:[{Name:col1 Value:value7} {Name:col2 Value:value8} {Name:col3 Value:value9} {Name:col4 Value:valueA}]}]}
EOF
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JA4CVwpDrx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of issue you're dealing with, but your XML actually looks like a stream of XML values, so you should decode it as such:

```
type Table struct {
    Name string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Rows []Row  `xml:"row"`
}

type Row struct {
    Cols []Col `xml:"col"`
}

type Col struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Value string `xml:",chardata"`
}

//...

var err error
dec := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(b))
for err == nil {
    t := Table{}
    err = dec.Decode(&t)
    fmt.Printf("%v, %+v\n", err, t)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/w4PqLv-Uc0.

---

**EDIT:** If you want to decode such XML directly into appropriate structs, you'll need a more complex machinery. Here's an example for users:

```
type User struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Surname string
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    var err error

    type col struct {
        Name  string `xml:"name,attr"`
        Value string `xml:",chardata"`
    }

    for {
        c := col{}
        err = d.Decode(&c)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }

            return err
        }
        switch c.Name {
        case "id":
            u.ID, err = strconv.Atoi(c.Value)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        case "name":
            u.Name = c.Value
            continue
        case "surname":
            u.Surname = c.Value
        }
    }

    return nil
}

type UserTable struct {
    Users []User `xml:"row"`
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Hqta3Ngjo3.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't clear enough in my first question so I have edited it with some more details

Answer (score 1):

To unmarshal each field into a different type based on the name, you'll need to get each start element token, check the name, and then decode as appropriate. Something like the following (where `getName` is a function that returns the `name` attribute; see the playground link for a minimal working example):

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(…)
for {
    tok, err := d.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    start, ok := tok.(xml.StartElement)
    if !ok {
        // This is chardata or some other token.
        // If it's bad XML, it will be caught on the next call to Token()
        continue
    }
    switch getName(start) {
    case "user":
        u := &User{}
        err = d.DecodeElement(u, &start)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // Do whatever you want to do with your struct here.
        fmt.Printf("Decoded a user: %+v\n", u)
    case "category":
        u := &Category{}
        err = d.DecodeElement(u, &start)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Decoded a category: %+v\n", u)
    default:
        // If the name is unrecognized, skip the rest of the element.
        // We could also return an error
        d.Skip()
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/l7Vmj_8Igp