# How to get the json field names of a struct in golang?

Tags: json, go, struct, field

What is the way to get the json field names of this struct ?

```
type example struct {
    Id          int `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt   string `json:"created_at"`
    Tag         string `json:"tag"`
    Text        string `json:"text"`
    AuthorId    int `json:"author_id"`
}
```

I try to print the fields with this function :

```
func (b example) PrintFields() {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    for i := 0; i < val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Name)
    }
}
```

Of course I get :

```
Id
CreatedAt
Tag
Text
AuthorId
```

But I would like something like :

```
id
created_at
tag
text
author_id
```

Comment: Check out this answer (it contains an example to get tag values): [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You use the [StructTag](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) type to get the tags. The documentation I linked has examples, look them up, but your code could be something like

```
func (b example) PrintFields() {
  val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
  for i := 0; i < val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
     fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("json"))
  }
}
```

**NOTE** The `json` tag format supports more than just field names, such as `omitempty` or `string`, so if you need an approach that takes care of that too, further improvements to the `PrintFields` function should be made:

1. we need to check whether the `json` tag is `-` (i.e. `json:"-"`)
2. we need to check if name exists and isolate it

Something like this:

```
func (b example) PrintFields() {
  val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
  for i := 0; i < val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
    t := val.Type().Field(i)
    fieldName := t.Name

    switch jsonTag := t.Tag.Get("json"); jsonTag {
    case "-":
    case "":
        fmt.Println(fieldName)
    default:
        parts := strings.Split(jsonTag, ",")
        name := parts[0]
        if name == "" {
            name = fieldName
        }
        fmt.Println(name)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the `json` tag supports more than just the name of the property, such as `<name>,omitempty` and your code is going to fail that by returning more than just the name of the field.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `StructField`'s `Name`, you can use `Tag` to get a `StructTag` object.
See: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag

Then you can use `StructTag`'s `Get` or `Lookup` methods to get the json tag:

Using `Get`:

```
func (b example) PrintFields() {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    for i := 0; i < val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
        // prints empty line if there is no json tag for the field
        fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("json"))
    }
}
```

Using `Lookup`:

```
func (b example) PrintFields() {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    for i := 0; i < val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
        // skips fields without json tag
        if tag, ok := val.Type().Field(i).Tag.Lookup("json"); ok {
            fmt.Println(tag)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
func (b example) PrintFields() {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    t := val.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(t.Field(i).Tag.Get("json"))
    }
}
```

See it in [playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/ki8azJtkNH)

Comment: As `val` is not used in the snippet this can now be simplified to `t := reflect.TypeOf(b)` - https://go.dev/play/p/tqtlOkmA20x

Answer (score 3):

an updated version with a generic interface as parameter:

```
func PrintFields(b interface{}) {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    for i := 0; i < val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
        t := val.Type().Field(i)
        fieldName := t.Name

        if jsonTag := t.Tag.Get("json"); jsonTag != "" && jsonTag != "-" {
            // check for possible comma as in "...,omitempty"
            var commaIdx int
            if commaIdx = strings.Index(jsonTag, ","); commaIdx < 0 {
                commaIdx = len(jsonTag)
            }
            fieldName = jsonTag[:commaIdx]
        }
        fmt.Println(fieldName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func (e example) GetJsonField() []string {
    b := example{}
    marshaled, _ := json.Marshal(b)
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    _ = json.Unmarshal(marshaled, &m)
    
    result := make([]string, 0)
    for k := range m {
        result = append(result, k)
    }
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the `Name` you are looking for. What you looking is the `Tag`

```
func (b example) PrintFields() {
    val := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    for i := 0; i < val.Type().NumField(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(val.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("json"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Json field name Using Struct Field Name

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(structobject)    
field, _ := val.Type().FieldByName("Id")
fmt.Println(field.Tag.Get("json"))
```