# String literals in GO structure definition

Tags: go, struct

In this structure definition:

```
type API struct {
    Message string "json:message"
}
```

what is the meaning of the string ***"json:message"*** and how to access it if it is accessible.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's called [struct tag](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types).  Possible duplicate of [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Comment: @RdB below is an answer with example , please accept the answer if that helped you / satsfied the requirements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are struct tags. This struct tag is used by package 
`encoding/json`  to `Marshal` objects to JSON  and `Unmarshal`  JSON string to objects

while  marshaling (encoding ) a struct to JSON string it will look for this struct tag to assign `JSON`  key name, if not present it may use the struct field name itself

btw the syntax is wrong it has to be

```
type API struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}
```

Here is a sample program for reference https://play.golang.org/p/FsMGNuDB8P