# structs with multiple mapping notations

Tags: go, struct, orm, dto

I have these two structs which represent the same entities (one comes from a Json file and the other from a DB)

```
type DriverJson struct {
    ID            int    `json:"id"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
}

type DriverOrm struct {
    ID            int       `orm:"column(id);auto"`
    Name          string    `orm:"column(name);size(255);null"`
}
```

I want to merge them into one Driver struct, how do I merge the mapping notations (orm:, json:)?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation of [`reflect.StructTag`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag), by convention the value of a tag string is a space-separated `key:"value"` pairs, so simply:

```
type DriverJson struct {
    ID   int    `json:"id" orm:"column(id);auto"`
    Name string `json:"name" orm:"column(name);size(255);null`
}
```

For details, see [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)