# I dont understand what those '' field mean in a structure for database, what it is the purpose of

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

```
type User struct {
  Id   int    `orm:"auto"`
  Name string `orm:"size(100)"`
}
```

what the purpose of 'orm:"auto"' and 'orm:"size(100)"'.

i mean i know those field corresponds to the limits that i have set in my database, but why they are here in the code ? why there is not a structure like this ?

```
type User struct {
  Id   int    
  Name string 
}
```

does it changes something ? i dont understand. thanks for reading and helping me.

Comment: Did you mean `gorm:"auto"` or am I reading the wrong documentation?

Comment: [It looks like you're being dishonest about using GORM](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/orm). Still, I think my answer applies.

Comment: They are called _tags_, and they allow you to attach any meta-information to the fields, in this case will be used by some ORM implementation (e.g. `gorm` package). See [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Comment: @icza: Should be an answer

Comment: So, did you get your answer?

Comment: Yup, great answers thank you

Answer (score 1):

<sup>First of all, it appears that you are not using GORM but [something else](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/orm). I will assume that herein.</sup>

> does it changes something ?

Yes. These are tags that add extra attributes to the field in question.

For example, `"auto"` makes the field auto-increment, and `"size(100)"`… well, I think you can probably guess if you apply a little brainpower!

> why there is not a structure like this ?

There is!

The following alternative structure is perfectly valid, just not what the author of your code intended:

```
type Result struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}
```

Consult [the documentation](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/models.md) to discover what tags you can use. You'll have to read more than just the first few paragraphs of the package description to find out how the technology works!

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Never used Go or this library in my life. The above comes from a quick Google and glance at the manual.</sub>