# go mongodb driver and struct, find messes with uppercase and lowercase

Tags: mongodb, go, database

```
var Messages []Token
c2 := session.DB("mydatabase").C("pages")
query2 := c2.Find(bson.M{}).All(&Messages)
fmt.Print(Messages)
```

Here's the structure in my Mongo DB:

```
id_
pageUrl
token
pageId
```

I first tried the structure as this:

```
type Token struct {
    PageUrl string
    Token string
    PageId string
}
```

but only the token was being printed, perhaps because it's all lowercase. The other two fields were not being retrieved because they contain uppercase. Then I tried this:

```
type Token struct {
    PageUrl string `json: "pageUrl" bson: "pageUrl"`
    Token string `json: "token" bson: "token"`
    PageId string `json: "pageId" bson: "pageId"`
}
```

what are those `bson` and `json` things? I've only put it there because I've seen in the internet, but it doesn't work, I still get only the `token` field

**UPDATE with solution and tested example for nested documents**

I've seen that there was no posts regarding this question so remember that the solution was to remove the spaces between `json:` and `bson:` 
Also, to help someone who might be wondering how to do it for nested structs, here I give two structures that worked for me:

```
type Token struct {
    PageUrl string `json:"pageUrl" bson:"pageUrl"`
    Token string `json:"token" bson:"token"`
    PageId string `json:"pageId" bson:"pageId"`
}


type Message struct {
    Sender struct {
        Id string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    } `json:"sender" bson:"sender"`
    Recipient struct {
        Id string `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    } `json:"recipient" bson:"recipient"`
    Message struct {
        Mid string `json:"mid" bson:"mid"`
        Seq int `json:"seq" bson:"seq"`
        Message string `json:"text" bson:"text"`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

these `json` and `bson` stuff is called [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go)

My best guess is that because Go requires a variable or function to be public by Capitalize the first character, so serialize frameworks like json or bson require the struct Capitalize its first character to expose the field(so that it could see the field). Thus the exposed field name should be defined with a tag (to avoid the restriction).

the space between `bson:` and `"token"` seems to have cause the problem

I tried following code snippet and seems works fine.

```
type Token struct {
    PageUrl string `json:"pageUrl" bson:"pageUrl"`
    Token string `json:"token" bson:"token"`
    PageId string `json:"pageId" bson:"pageId"`
}
```

Comment: Thank you for testing it on your PC. I also added an update with code for nested structs in case someone finds it useful, i've seen that there's no information on that in google or stackoverflow