# Func pipe in go Language

Tags: go

is it possible to create function pipelines in go language, where output of one function is directly conventionality into input of another function.

Please discuss it in the comments if it's not clear and you need more info.

Other functional languages provide some constructs, for instance it's `then` in javascript with `promises`, in java they use `andThen` with `lambdas`, and with `c#` it's `FunctionExtensions`. Shell programs like unix also provides buitin method called pipes `|`

```
func processA(test TestObj) {
    // do something
    return test
}

func process B(test TestObj) {
    //do something
    return test
}

func processC(test TestObj) {
    //do something
    return test
}
```

so can we do something similar like

```
var obj = TestObj{}

processA(obj)
   .then(processB)
    .then(processC)
```

jim, the second example uses the channels? can you please provide a code example using my code.

Comment: What do you actually want to accomplish? Go doesn't use various extra constructions just for the sake of syntax. You can call `fnC(fnB(fnA()))` if you want, or simply collect each result and call the next. If you want other pipeline patterns the first 2 results in google are https://blog.golang.org/pipelines and https://blog.gopheracademy.com/composable-pipelines-pattern/

Comment: Golang is not NodeJS buddy. As @JimB said you can simply achieve what you need just executing this functions in order `fnC(fnB(fnA()))`.

Comment: Jim, is the second link uses channels? can you please help with some code using my example, i'm new to go

Comment: @Devyiweid: if you're not dealing with concurrency, just start by calling the functions one after the other. I don't know what your actual problem is, so I have no idea how that would adapt to another pattern.

Comment: there's no actual problem, it's something i need to implement for my projects, and last resort i'll use your suggestion i.e. to nest calls but if you can write something based on the links you suggested, i can build something on it. it's research trying to find out a way and the link you mentioned looks promising. the attempt is to find a more readable ways to do this, for instance `.then` based constructs are more readable then deeply nested functions.

Comment: maybe if there's library for that?

Comment: @Devyiweid: I've never needed a library to call a series of functions, and you don't need to nest functions to call them serially. Trying to translate patterns directly between different languages is often a waste of time. Don't try to write javascript or C# in Go, learn how to write Go first.

Comment: can you please write a channel based solution for above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go)

Answer (score 2):

I was seeking for this kind of pattern as well without any luck. It's very common to other language but not in golang

Anyway, you may find this usefull https://github.com/open-zhy/fn-pipe

It basically uses [reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection) in order to map all your inputs and outputs through your functions

Answer (score 0):

I am also not exactly sure what you want to do, however here is an example of a linked list implementation in Go.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type LinkedList struct {
    value interface{}
    next  *LinkedList
}

func (oldNode *LinkedList) prepend(value interface{}) *LinkedList {
    return &LinkedList{value, oldNode}
}

func tail(value interface{}) *LinkedList {
    return &LinkedList{value, nil}
}

func traverse(ll *LinkedList) {
    if ll == nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(ll.value)
    traverse(ll.next)
}

func main() {
    node := tail(5).prepend(6).prepend(7)
    traverse(node)
}
```

So, as you can see, it is possible to `chain` methods using what is known as the `fluent` or `builder` interface. IMO above example is an appropriate place to do so. https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Now if you want to do an async / non blocking request, then I would use channels / goroutines. It's not really a promise, but you can certainly handle on success/error if you wanted.

```
func NonBlockingGet(url string) <-chan []byte {
    c := make(chan []byte, 1)

    go func() {
        var body []byte
        defer func() {
            c <- body
        }()

        res, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer res.Body.Close()

        body, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    }()

    return c
}

func main() {
    promise := NonBlockingGet("http://example.com")

    // can do other stuff here - because doing a non-blocking get request.
    log.Println("This will output before the response length")

    body := <- promise // Will wait here till promise is resolved.
    log.Printf("response length: %d", len(body))
}
```

I hope that this helps. As said in comments above, this is not javascript and we shouldnt try to be. However, instead of assigning `<- promise` to `body`, you could always pass `<- promise` as an argument into a function.