# Retrieve annotations on structs' variables using reflection

Tags: go

In go, is it possible to retrieve structs' variable annotation? Considering the following struct:

```
type AType struct {
    ID        string    `xml:"my_id"`
    Date      string    `xml:"creation_ts"`
}
```

How can I retrieve the `xml:"my_id"` part for the ID field using reflection ? The following will print the name, type and value of the variable but not the *annotation*.

```
s := reflect.ValueOf(&aType).Elem()
typeOfT := s.Type()
for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
    s.Field(i).
    f := s.Field(i)
    fmt.Printf("%d: %s %s = %v\n", i,
        typeOfT.Field(i).Name, f.Type(), f.Interface())
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Example how it can be done is in this answer: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is available as `StructField.Tag`, so

```
f.Tag
```

References:

- [reflect.StructField](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField)
- [reflect.StructTag](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag)

A working example, credits [@mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva): https://play.golang.org/p/reY-IDCyaq