# Custom JSON mapping function in Go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

So I'm making a Go service that makes a call to a restful API, I have no control over the API I'm calling.

I know that Go has a nice built in deserializer in NewDecoder->Decode, but it only works for struct fields that start with capital letters (aka public fields). Which poses a problem because the JSON I'm trying to consume looks like this:

```
{
    "_next": "someValue",
    "data":  [{/*a collection of objects*/}],
    "message": "success"
}
```

How the heck would I map `"_next"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to specify the field name in JSON. The JSON object you posted above can be modeled like this:

```
type Something struct {
    Next    string        `json:"_next"`
    Data    []interface{} `json:"data"`
    Message string        `json:"message"`
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    var sg Something
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &sg); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", sg)
}

const s = `{
    "_next": "someValue",
    "data":  ["one", 2],
    "message": "success"
}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NJCkBpzdfn)):

```
{Next:someValue Data:[one 2] Message:success}
```

Also note that you may also unmarshal into maps or `interface{}` values, so you don't even have to create structs, but it won't be as convenient using it as the structs:

```
func main() {
    var m map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", m)
}

const s = `{
    "_next": "someValue",
    "data":  ["one", 2],
    "message": "success"
}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cuKkKmlp5a)):

```
map[_next:someValue data:[one 2] message:success]
```

Comment: Ahh perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Quick follow up, when I serialize this object back into json, is there a way for me to change the field name? Like read from 'disc_firstname' and then when serializing back into json, have it map to 'firstname'?

Comment: @cDecker32 The names specified in the tags will be used both when marshaling and unmarshaling.

Comment: So no way to provide a value for mashalling and a different one for unmarshalling on the same struct?

Comment: @cDecker32 Not with tags. You may implement `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` to do custom conversion, doing whatever you want to in them.

Answer (score 0):

Tags will solve your problem.

Hoping it may help others who come here, you can make use of https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to generate Go structs. Paste a JSON structure on the left and the equivalent Go type will be generated to the right, which you can paste into your program.