# Storing long text in Datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Is Datastore suitable to store really long text, e.g. profile descriptions and articles?

If not, what's the Google Cloud alternative?

If yes, what would be the ideal way to store it in order to maintain formatting such as linebreaks and markdown supported keywords? Simply store as string or convert to byte? And should I be worried about dirty user input?

I need it for a Go project (I don't think language is relevant, but maybe Go have some useful features for this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's suitable if you're OK with certain limitations.

These limitations are:

- the overall entity size (properties + indices) must not exceed 1 MB (this should be OK for profiles and most articles)
- texts longer than a certain limit (currently 1500 bytes) cannot be indexed, so the entity may store a longer string, but you won't be able to search in it / include it in query filters; don't forget to [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) these fields with `"noindex"`

As for the type, you may simply use `string`, e.g.:

```
type Post struct {
    UserID  int64  `datastore:"uid"`
    Content string `datastore:"content,noindex"`
}
```

`string` types preserve all formatting, including newlines, HTML, markup and whatever formatting.

*"Dirty user input?"* That's the issue of rendering / presenting the data. The datastore will not try to interpret it or attempt to perform any action based on its content, nor will transform it. So from the Datastore point of view, you have nothing to worry about (you don't create text GQLs by appending text ever, right?!).

Also note that if you're going to store large texts in your entities, those large texts will be fetched whenever you load / query such entities, and you also must send it when you modify and (re)save such an entity.

**Tip #1:** Use [projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#Query.Project) if you don't need the whole texts in certain queries to avoid "big" data movement (and so to ultimately speed up queries).

**Tip #2:** To "ease" the burden of not being able to index large texts, you may add duplicate properties like a short summary or title of the large text, because `string` values shorter than 1500 bytes can be indexed.

**Tip #3:** If you want to go over the 1 MB entity size limit, or you just want to generally decrease your datastore size usage, you may opt to store large texts *compressed* inside entities. Since they are long, you can't search / filter them anyway, but they are very well compressed (often below 40% of the original). So if you have many long texts, you can shrink your datastore size to like 1 third just by storing all texts compressed. Of course this will add to the entity save / load time (as you have to compress / decompress the texts), but often it is still worth it.

Comment: You are my hero <3.. regarding the noindex tag, most of the articles I've read, [such as this one](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml) set the indexes using a yaml file.. but your code makes me wonder if it's also possible to set index in the struct like you just did, e.g. `datastore:"index"`?

Comment: @fisker You use the index configuration file (e.g. `index.yaml`) to define the _composite_ indices. What you specify in the tag of a struct field only tells if that property is indexed (or in other words: if the entity is indexed by that property). These are 2 different things.

Comment: if I understand correctly then it's not necessary to specify `datastore:",index"` because the fields already take advantage of built-in indices? So assuming the Post struct had a Date and a Tag field, then it wouldn't be necessary to do anything to filter the Tag field since it can be achieved with equality filters, whereas for the Date field then it would be recommended to define composite indices in order to perform filters that sort by date? (sorry for being off-topic and taking advantage of your brilliance)

Comment: @fisker Fields (except for `[]byte`) are indexed by default, so specifying the `"index"` tag is not needed. You create composite indices to support more advanced queries that include inequality filters and sorting. For more on the topic, read [Cloud Datastore Indexes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/indexes) and [Index Selection and Advanced Search](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection).