# Is it possible to use multiple annotations in beego?

Tags: go, struct, model, annotations, beego

I have model like:

```
type Service struct {
    Id       uint64 
    Name     string 
    Secret   string 
    Disabled bool
}
```

And want to use annotations like `form`, `valid` and `orm`. And I can't find how I should declare these annotations. Should it be one or many? If many, what separator should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [`reflect.StructTag`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag):

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs.

So you may specify multiple key-value pairs separated by space, like:

```
type Service struct {
    Id uint64 `form:"id" valid:"Range(1, 999)" orm:"auto"`
}
```

See more about tags in this answer: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Comment: tank you!
should I set `orm:"id"` or it's ok to miss it ad it will be with some kind of autogenerating?

Comment: @OleksandrSavchenko You can leave it out, it was just an example. Read more about it here: [Models – Beego ORM](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/overview.md).