# Can't unmarshall JSON with key names having spaces

Tags: json, go, struct

Some JSON data I am getting have spaces in the key names. I am using standard `encoding/json` library to unmarshal the data. However it is unable to understand the keys with spaces in the schema. For e.g. following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var jsonBlob = []byte(`[
        {"Na me": "Platypus", "Order": "Monotremata"},
        {"Na me": "Quoll",    "Order": "Dasyuromorphia"}
    ]`)
    type Animal struct {
        Name  string `json: "Na me"`
        Order string `json: "Order,omitempty"`
    }
    var animals []Animal
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob, &animals)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", animals)
}
```

Gives the output as:

```
[{Name: Order:Monotremata} {Name: Order:Dasyuromorphia}]
```

So in the schema the library removes the space(from **Na me**) and try to find the key (**Name**), which is obviously not present. Any suggestion what can I do here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `json` [tag specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) is incorrect, that's why the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) library defaults to the field name which is `Name`. But since there is no JSON field with `"Name"` key, `Animal.Name` will remain its zero value (which is the empty string `""`).

Unmarshaling `Order` will still work, because the `json` package will use the field name if `json` tag specification is missing (tries with both lower and upper-case). Since the field name is identical to the JSON key, it works without extra JSON tag mapping.

You can't have a space in the tag specification after the colon and before the quotation mark:

```
type Animal struct {
    Name  string `json:"Na me"`
    Order string `json:"Order,omitempty"`
}
```

With this simple change, it works (try it on the [Go Playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/ij_EunyeJB):

```
[{Name:Platypus Order:Monotremata} {Name:Quoll Order:Dasyuromorphia}]
```

Comment: Ouch, that solved. thanks. However still didn't understand completely. why order key is working in that case...

Comment: ah understood, here order key name was same as schema

Comment: Just to make this clearer, in case of the incorrectly specified struct (just the tag actually) with space in between json and attribute name, it totally ignores the tag spec since it contains a space after "json:"  (invalid) & tries to map the field names directly. So it works only for "Order" and not "Na me" (even if we chang the Order tag to any junk value e.g change that line to: Order string `json: "ABCD,omitempty"` it'll still work)