# Go Google Datastore nulls

Tags: google-app-engine, go, struct, null, google-cloud-datastore

I have datastore objects that look like:

```
created (timestamp)
guid (string)
details (string)
start (string)
end (string
```

Often, the `details`, `start` or `end` are `NULL`.

In Go, I am trying to do this:

```
    type Edge struct {
        created   time.Time
        details   string `datastore: "details,omitempty"`
        guid      string `datastore: "guid,omitempty"`
        start     string `datastore: "start,omitempty"`
        end       string `datastore: "end,omitempty"`
    }

    for t := client.Run(ctx, q); ; {
        var x Edge
        key, err := t.Next(&x)
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error caught: %v\n\n", err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Key=%v\nEdge=%#v\n\n", key, x)
    }
```

The output error is always something like:

```
error caught: datastore: cannot load field "guid" into a "main.Edge": no such struct field

Key=/edges,4503602429165568
Edge=main.Edge{created:time.Time{wall:0x0, ext:0, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}, details:"", guid:"", start:"", end:""}
```

When I search for that key in the datastore console, I see that `guid` is a valid `string`.

`GetAll` gave me almost the same problem.

My questions are:

- I'm new to Go. Is there anything specific I'm doing wrong here? (Any typos would be Stackoverflow specific. Because I changed a few things here)
- Is there anyway to see what datastore is sending back to be before putting it in a struct?
- Some of the values will sometimes be `null`. Like `start`, `end` and `details`. Is that valid for a `string` in a struct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems that stand out immediately:

1. Struct fields must be exported, so start their names with capital letter.
2. Your [tag values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) are "invalid" (they don't follow the conventions). You must not leave a space between the key `datastore:` and the value `"details,omitempty"`.

So use the following struct definition:

```
type Edge struct {
    Created time.Time `datastore:"created"`
    Details string    `datastore:"details,omitempty"`
    Guid    string    `datastore:"guid,omitempty"`
    Start   string    `datastore:"start,omitempty"`
    End     string    `datastore:"end,omitempty"`
}
```

See similar questions for the above-mentioned 2 problems:

[golang mgo getting empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508642/golang-mgo-getting-empty-objects/45508761#45508761)

[Why struct fields are showing empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674913/why-struct-fields-are-showing-empty/32674930#32674930)

If a property in the Datastore is `null`, that's not a problem for a Go struct. In such case the corresponding struct field will be the [zero-value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of its type, which is the empty string `""` in case of the `string` type. If you want to be able to differentiate between the Datastore `null`, Datastore "missing property" and the actual empty string `""`, you may change the field type to be a pointer (like `*string`), in which case the missing property and the `null` value will correspond to a `nil` pointer value, and an existing but empty string value will be a non-`nil` pointer to an empty string value.

Comment: That was it! Follow up question: Is there a way to have noindex and omitempty in the same tag?

Comment: @Chemdream Separate them with a comma, e.g. `datastore:"end,omitempty,noindex"`, but consult the docs if that's supported.

Comment: Unrelated to this question but I thought you might want to share where `iterator.Done` comes from. 

I went through the google cloud go client library and I see it imported from `"google.golang.org/api/iterator"`. Did you just import it in the same file as your query functions?