# Sending boolean value through application/json curl request

Tags: json, curl, go

I'm trying to send a curl request. This is my request:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"tahereh","password":"1234", "admin":true}' http://localhost:8000/users
```

I decode this request in my code and store it in 'user var' of code's User struct, like this:

```
var newUser models.User //User is an struct in model package
err1 := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&newUser)
```

Then I debug my code with `dlv debug` command line. My problem is when I print `newUser` with `print newUser` in `dlv` all of the variable correctly set except the boolean value. While I'm sending the true value through curl request, it sets to false!

point:  I have printed the err1, it's also null.

Comment: Post your `models.User` type.

Comment: type User struct {
 ID       uint64   `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREAMENT"`
Username string   `json:"username,omitempty" gorm:"size:100;not null;unique"`
  Password string   `json:"password,omitempty" gorm:"size:200;not null"`
  Admin    bool     `json:"admin" gorm:"not null;default=flase"`
   Charges  Charge `json:"charges,omitempty" gorm:"ForeignKey:UserID"`       Incomes  Income `json:"incomes,omitempty" gorm:"ForeignKey:UserID"`
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `models.User` type you explicitly specified to exclude the `Admin` field from JSON processing (this is what the `json:"-"` tag value means), so its value is left to its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) (which is `false` for the `bool` type).

Change its tag to `json:"admin"` and so its value will be set from the JSON `"admin"` property, like in this example:

```
type User {
    // your other fields...
    Admin bool `json:"admin" gorm:"not null;default=false"`
}
```

Read more about struct tags here: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Answer (score 0):

In principle, this should work:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    Admin    bool
}

func main() {
    var u User
    // var u models.User
    j := []byte(`{"username":"tahereh","password":"1234", "admin":true}`)
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &u)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error:%v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("User:%v", u)
}
```

Since it works partially for you, the json is probably being read ok. So perhaps take this sample code, and start by using your models.User type in place of User, and see if it still unmarshals ok.