# What is "valid" tag in structures

Tags: go

```
type MyRequest struct {
    email         string `json:"email" valid:"email,required"`
}
```

`json` is used to (un)marshal JSON structures, but what `valid` is for?

Comment: That tag is most likely used by a struct validation library.

Comment: I now also included `"valid"` in the list of commonly used tag keys here: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is used by this package: https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator

Answer (score 6):

It's for anything that reads it.  There's no official registry of tags (unless you count the ones used by the standard library).

Based on the semantics of the tag's value, one can reasonably assume it's used by some (likely more than one) validation library of some sort. The best way to find out its intended use is to look at the code that sets the tag, and see if it uses (or is used by) some library that sets that tag.  Unfortunately, there's no mechanical way to do this--you'll probably be looking through "import" lines and grepping package source code.