# Unmarshal json string to a struct that have one element of the struct itself

Tags: json, go, struct

I am go beginner and trying to unmarshal the following json string

```
[{
    "db": {
        "url": "mongodb://localhost",
        "port": "27000",
        "uname": "",
        "pass": "",
        "authdb": "",
        "replicas": [
            {
                "rs01": {
                    "url":"mongodb://localhost",
                    "port": "27001",
                    "uname": "",
                    "pass": "",
                    "authdb": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "rs02": {
                    "url":"mongodb://localhost",
                    "port": "27002",
                    "uname": "",
                    "pass": "",
                    "authdb": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

here is the struct

```
type DBS struct {
    URL      string `json:url`
    Port     string `json:port`
    Uname    string `json:uname`
    Pass     string `json:pass`
    Authdb   string `json:authdb`
    Replicas []DBS   `json:replicas`
}
```

and here is the function

```
func loadConfigs() []DBS {
    var config []DBS
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./config.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    json.Unmarshal(raw, &config)
    return config
}
```

The function is returning

```
{     []}
```

Comment: you're not checking the error returned from unmarshal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON input is not a slice of `DBS`, as there is another JSON object wrapper, and a value of `DBS` belongs to the property `"db"`.

Going deeper, the `"replicaps"` is a JSON array with objects holding varying keys, their values being representable by `DBS`.

So to fully describe your JSON, you need some kind of "dynamic" type. A map is such a dynamic type for example.

So your original JSON input can be fully modeled with the type: `[]map[string]DBS`. It's a slice of maps, as your JSON input contains a JSON array. And the map key can model any property name, and the value is a JSON object modeled by the `DBS` struct.

See this example which fully parses the JSON input:

```
type DBS struct {
    URL      string           `json:"url"`
    Port     string           `json:"port"`
    Uname    string           `json:"uname"`
    Pass     string           `json:"pass"`
    Authdb   string           `json:"authdb"`
    Replicas []map[string]DBS `json:"replicas"`
}

func main() {
    var dbs []map[string]DBS
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &dbs); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", dbs)
}
```

Note the proper [tag syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) (e.g. `json:"url"`).

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2yDvQCK0Ty)):

`[map[db:{URL:mongodb://localhost Port:27000 Uname: Pass: Authdb: Replicas:[map[rs01:{URL:mongodb://localhost Port:27001 Uname: Pass: Authdb: Replicas:[]}] map[rs02:{URL:mongodb://localhost Port:27002 Uname: Pass: Authdb: Replicas:[]}]]}]]`

Note that you can further model the first level which is always `"db"`, and we can switch to pointers (I used non-pointers in the first example so the printed result is readable):

```
type DBReplicated struct {
    DB *DBS `json:"db"`
}

type DBS struct {
    URL      string            `json:"url"`
    Port     string            `json:"port"`
    Uname    string            `json:"uname"`
    Pass     string            `json:"pass"`
    Authdb   string            `json:"authdb"`
    Replicas []map[string]*DBS `json:"replicas"`
}

func main() {
    var dbs []*DBReplicated
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &dbs); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db := dbs[0].DB
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", db)
    for _, dbs := range db.Replicas {
        for name, replica := range dbs {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %+v\n", name, replica)
        }
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AF8g4gVdp_)):

```
&{URL:mongodb://localhost Port:27000 Uname: Pass: Authdb: Replicas:[map[rs01:0x10538200] map[rs02:0x10538240]]}
rs01: &{URL:mongodb://localhost Port:27001 Uname: Pass: Authdb: Replicas:[]}
rs02: &{URL:mongodb://localhost Port:27002 Uname: Pass: Authdb: Replicas:[]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write your own `json.Unmarshaler` implementation if, for some reason, you're stuck with the already existing `DBS` structure.

*(In the below example I do actually change the structure a little to keep track of the name/key but that's optional, it's not necessary to make the unmarshaling work.)*

```
type DBS struct {
    name     string

    URL      string `json:url`
    Port     string `json:port`
    Uname    string `json:uname`
    Pass     string `json:pass`
    Authdb   string `json:authdb`
    Replicas []DBS  `json:replicas`
}

func (db *DBS) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    raw := map[string]json.RawMessage{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &raw); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(raw) > 1 {
        return fmt.Errorf("fail")
    }

    type _DBS DBS
    _db := (*_DBS)(db)
    for name, v := range raw {
        db.name = name
        return json.Unmarshal(v, _db)
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/c288n7holS