# How to decode complicated unnamed JSON in Golang

Tags: json, go, decode

I am currently trying to decode the following JSON structure:

```
[
    {
        "2015-08-14 19:29:48-04:00": {
            "value": "0.1",
            "measurement_tag_id": "0.1.1a",
            "UTC_time": "2015-08-14 23:29:48",
            "error": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "2015-08-14 19:37:07-04:00": {
            "value": "0.1",
            "measurement_tag_id": "0.1.1b",
            "UTC_time": "2015-08-14 23:37:07",
            "error": "0"
        }
    },
    {
        "2015-08-14 19:44:16-04:00": {
            "value": "0.1",
            "measurement_tag_id": "0.1.1b",
            "UTC_time": "2015-08-14 23:44:16",
            "error": "0"
        }
    }
]
```

This is to eventually have a slice of `Reading` structs, formatted as the following:

```
type reading struct {
    Value   string `json:"value"`
    MTID    string `json:"measurement_tag_id"`
    UTCTime string `json:"UTC_time"`
    Error   string `json:"error"`
}
```

I would then like to add this into an existing structure nested as:

```
type site struct {
    Name string
    ID   string
    Tags []tag
}

type tag struct {
    ID       string
    Readings []reading
}
```

I've currently been able to create the base structure for sites and tags from a more typical JSON payload with appropriate keys. I have been unsuccessful though in figuring out how to decode the reading JSON. So far the closest I have gotten is via `map[string]interface{}` chaining, but this feels incredibly clunky and verbose.

Solution so far for reference:

```
var readingData []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(file, &readingData); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    readings := readingData[0].(map[string]interface{})
    firstReading := readings["2015-08-14 19:29:48-04:00"].(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Println(firstReading)
    value := firstReading["value"].(string)
    error := firstReading["error"].(string)
    MTID := firstReading["measurement_tag_id"].(string)
    UTCTime := firstReading["UTC_time"].(string)
    fmt.Println(value, error, MTID, UTCTime)
```

While I am not sure if its necessary yet, I would also like to hold on to the arbitrary date keys. My first thought was to create a function that returned a `map[string]reading` but I am not sure how feasible this is.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmarshal json string to a struct that have one element of the struct itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585279/unmarshal-json-string-to-a-struct-that-have-one-element-of-the-struct-itself/46585770#46585770).

Comment: The json data can be decoded into map[string]Reading. It's not clear to me what you want to do after Unmarshal. What stops you from creating site/tag structs and assigned the Reading value? Note that your struct type/names must be exported/upper case if you plan to unmarshal/marshal into json.

Answer (score 4):

You can have your `reading` type implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface.

```
func (r *reading) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type _r reading // same structure, but no methods, avoids infinite calls to this method
    m := map[string]_r{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, v := range m {
        *r = reading(v)
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7X1oB77XL4

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a slice of maps to parse, then copy to slice of readings, eg:

```
    var readingMaps []map[string]reading //slice of maps of string key to reading value

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &readingMaps); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    readings := []reading{}

    for _, m := range readingMaps {
        for _, r := range m {
            readings = append(readings, r)
        }
    }
```

[play.golang.org/p/jXTdmaZz7s](https://play.golang.org/p/jXTdmaZz7s)