# json error, cannot unmarshal object into Go value

Tags: json, go, struct, slice

I have this JSON data:

```
{
"InfoA" : [256,256,20000],
"InfoB" : [256,512,15000],
"InfoC" : [208,512,20000],
"DEFAULT" : [256,256,20000]
}
```

With [JSON-to-Go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/), I get this Go type definition:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    InfoA   []int `json:"InfoA"`
    InfoB   []int `json:"InfoB"`
    InfoC   []int `json:"InfoC"`
    DEFAULT []int `json:"DEFAULT"`
}
```

With this code ([play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/k_ly0IGH1A))

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    type paramsInfo struct {
        InfoA   []int `json:"InfoA"`
        InfoB   []int `json:"InfoB"`
        InfoC   []int `json:"InfoC"`
        DEFAULT []int `json:"DEFAULT"`
    }
    rawJSON := []byte(`{
"InfoA" : [256,256,20000],
"InfoB" : [256,512,15000],
"InfoC" : [208,512,20000],
"DEFAULT" : [256,256,20000]
}`)
    var params []paramsInfo
    err := json.Unmarshal(rawJSON, &params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I get error `json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.paramsInfo`

I don't understand why. Can you help me?

Comment: What part of the error is confusing you? It tells you exactly the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JSON source is a single object, yet you try to unmarshal it into a slice. Change the type of `params` to `paramsInfo` (non-slice):

```
var params paramsInfo
err := json.Unmarshal(rawJSON, &params)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    os.Exit(1)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v", params)
```

And with that the output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d_a9i6A3BI)):

```
{InfoA:[256 256 20000] InfoB:[256 512 15000] InfoC:[208 512 20000]
    DEFAULT:[256 256 20000]}
```

Comment: How can I do without explictly declaring "InfoA  ", "InfoAB", etc in structs  ? 
I implemented a solution (https://play.golang.org/p/3NoMXoyOCU), but I got empty result. I don't see how it might be implemented.

Comment: @LeMoussel See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserlize-a-dynamic-json-in-golang/29347148#29347148) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585279/unmarshal-json-string-to-a-struct-that-have-one-element-of-the-struct-itself/46585770#46585770).

Comment: Solution: 
`params2 := make(map[string][]int)`
`_= json.Unmarshal(rawJSON, &params2)`
`fmt.Printf("\nparams2: %+v", params2)`

Answer (score 2):

You are decoding a single JSON object but you are attempting to put it into the `[]paramsInfo` slice.

It works fine when you decode JSON array of objects:

```
rawJSON := []byte(`[{
    "InfoA" : [256,256,20000],
    "InfoB" : [256,512,15000],
    "InfoC" : [208,512,20000],
    "DEFAULT" : [256,256,20000]
}]`)
```

(note the square brackets around your object)

By the way, in the `if` branch handling an error you don't need to call `err.Error()` to get the error string; `fmt.Println(err)` is sufficient and it's actually a Go idiom to use it like this. The implementation of `fmt.Print*` is taking care of handling the `error` type (contrary to `print` for example).