# Map response to a struct using Golang

Tags: go

I am attempting to map a response from an API to a struct using Golang.

The JSON that comes back when I view the link in the browser is below:

```
{
"GBP": 657.54
}
```

And I just want to map it to a simple struct like so:

```
type Price struct {
    Name  string
    Value float64
}
```

Here is my current code.

```
func FetchCoinPrice(fsym string, tsyms string) Price {
    url := fmt.Sprintf("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=" + fsym + "&tsyms=" + tsyms)

    fmt.Println("Requesting data from " + url)

    price := Price{}

    // getting the data using http
    request, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    // Read the response body using ioutil
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    defer request.Body.Close()

    if request.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
        json.Unmarshal(body, &price)
    }

    return price

}
```

At the moment all I receive is an empty struct, I know the link is bringing back the correct data and I've tested it in my browser.

Comment: Those are 2 different data structures. If you want to copy the values into a different structure, you have to do that manually.

Comment: You have to use something _dynamic_ to model your _dynamic_ input. See possible duplicates: [How to parse/deserlize a dynamic JSON in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347092/how-to-parse-deserlize-a-dynamic-json-in-golang/29347148#29347148); and [Unmarshal json string to a struct that have one element of the struct itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585279/unmarshal-json-string-to-a-struct-that-have-one-element-of-the-struct-itself/46585770#46585770).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mapping doesn't work that way. Instead, you should use a map:

```
    data := []byte(`{
       "GBP": 657.54
     }`)

    priceMap := map[string]float64{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &priceMap)
    // Check your errors!
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(priceMap)
```

This will print:

```
map[GBP:657.54]
```

You can then iterate over the map and build the struct you mentioned above, or just access the entry directly if you know the currency. eg: `priceMap["GBP"]`

You should really check your errors, especially if you're not getting the output you expect from `Unmarshal`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the unmarshaler cannot guess that *keys* in a JSON object should correspond to some *value* in a struct. Golang JSON mapping simply doesn't work that way.

However, you can make your "Price" type [implement `json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) to deserialize a message into a map of floats (`map[string]float64`) then ensure the shape is right and populate the struct accordingly:

```
func (p *Price) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {
  kvs := map[string]float64{}
  err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &kvs)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  if len(kvs) != 1 {
    return fmt.Errorf("expected 1 key, got %d", len(kvs))
  }
  for name, value := range kvs {
    p.Name, p.Value = name, value
  }
  return nil
}

func main() {
  jsonstr := `[{"GBP":657.54},{"USD":123.45}]`
  ps := []Price{}
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &ps)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  // ps=[]main.Price{
  //   main.Price{Name:"GBP", Value:657.54},
  //   main.Price{Name:"USD", Value:123.45}
  // }
}
```