# Mgo aggregation: how to reuse model types to query and unmarshal "mixed" results?

Tags: mongodb, go, types, aggregation-framework, mgo

Let's say we have 2 collections: `"users"` and `"posts"`, modeled by the following types:

```
type User struct {
    ID         string    `bson:"_id"`
    Name       string    `bson:"name"`
    Registered time.Time `bson:"registered"`
}

type Post struct {
    ID      string    `bson:"_id"`
    UserID  string    `bson:"userID"`
    Content string    `bson:"content"`
    Date    time.Time `bson:"date"`
}
```

These can be used when storing / retrieving individual or even collection of documents, e.g.:

```
usersColl := sess.DB("").C("users")
postsColl := sess.DB("").C("posts")

// Insert new user:
u := &User{
    ID:         "1",
    Name:       "Bob",
    Registered: time.Now(),
},
err := usersColl.Insert(u)
// Handle err

// Get Posts in the last 10 mintes:
var posts []*Post
err := postsColl.Find(
    bson.M{"date": bson.M{"$gt": time.Now().Add(-10 * time.Minute)}},
).Limit(20).All(&posts)
// Handle err
```

What if we use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to fetch a mixture of these documents? For example [`Collection.Pipe()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Pipe):

```
// Query users with their posts:
pipe := collUsers.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "posts",
            "localField":   "_id",
            "foreignField": "userID",
            "as":           "posts",
        },
    },
})

var doc bson.M
it := pipe.Iter()
for it.Next(&doc) {
    fmt.Println(doc)
}
// Handle it.Err()
```

We query users with their posts in a single query. The result is a mixture of users and posts. How can we reuse our `User` and `Post` model types to not have to deal with the result as "raw" documents (of type `bson.M`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query above returns documents that "almost" match `User` documents, but they also have the posts of each users. So basically the result is a series of `User` documents with a `Post` array or slice *embedded*.

One way would be to add a `Posts []*Post` field to the `User` itself, and we would be done:

```
type User struct {
    ID         string    `bson:"_id"`
    Name       string    `bson:"name"`
    Registered time.Time `bson:"registered"`
    Posts      []*Post   `bson:"posts,omitempty"`
}
```

While this works, it seems "overkill" to extend `User` with `Posts` just for the sake of a single query. If we'd continue down this road, our `User` type would get bloated with lots of "extra" fields for different queries. Not to mention if we fill the `Posts` field and save the user, those posts would end up saved inside the `User` document. Not what we want.

Another way would be to create a `UserWithPosts` type copying `User`, and adding a `Posts []*Post` field. Needless to say this is ugly and inflexible (any changes made to `User` would have to be reflected to `UserWithPosts` manually).

### With Struct Embedding

Instead of modifying the original `User`, and instead of creating a new `UserWithPosts` type from "scratch", we can utilize [struct embedding](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) (reusing the existing `User` and `Post` types) with a little trick:

```
type UserWithPosts struct {
    User  `bson:",inline"`
    Posts []*Post `bson:"posts"`
}
```

Note the bson [tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) `",inline"`. This is documented at [`bson.Marshal()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Marshal) and [`bson.Unmarshal()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Unmarshal) (we'll use it for unmarshaling):

> ```
> inline     Inline the field, which must be a struct or a map.
>            Inlined structs are handled as if its fields were part
>            of the outer struct. An inlined map causes keys that do
>            not match any other struct field to be inserted in the
>            map rather than being discarded as usual.
> ```

By using embedding and the `",inline"` tag value, the `UserWithPosts` type itself will be a valid target for unmarshaling `User` documents, and its `Post []*Post` field will be a perfect choice for the looked up `"posts"`.

Using it:

```
var uwp *UserWithPosts
it := pipe.Iter()
for it.Next(&uwp) {
    // Use uwp:
    fmt.Println(uwp)
}
// Handle it.Err()
```

Or getting all results in one step:

```
var uwps []*UserWithPosts
err := pipe.All(&uwps)
// Handle error
```

The type declaration of `UserWithPosts` may or may not be a local declaration. If you don't need it elsewhere, it can be a local declaration in the function where you execute and process the aggregation query, so it will not bloat your existing types and declarations. If you want to reuse it, you can declare it at package level (exported or unexported), and use it wherever you need it.

### Modifying the aggregation

Another option is to use MongoDB's [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to "rearrange" the result documents, so a "simple" struct will perfectly cover the documents:

```
// Query users with their posts:
pipe := collUsers.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "posts",
            "localField":   "_id",
            "foreignField": "userID",
            "as":           "posts",
        },
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": bson.M{
            "newRoot": bson.M{
                "user":  "$$ROOT",
                "posts": "$posts",
            },
        },
    },
})
```

With this remapping, the result documents can be modeled like this:

```
type UserWithPosts struct {
    User  *User   `bson:"user"`
    Posts []*Post `bson:"posts"`
}
```

Note that while this works, the `posts` field of all documents will be fetched from the server twice: once as the `posts` field of the returned documents, and once as the field of `user`; we don't map / use it but it is present in the result documents. So if this solution is chosen, the `user.posts` field should be removed e.g. with a `$project` stage:

```
pipe := collUsers.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "posts",
            "localField":   "_id",
            "foreignField": "userID",
            "as":           "posts",
        },
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": bson.M{
            "newRoot": bson.M{
                "user":  "$$ROOT",
                "posts": "$posts",
            },
        },
    },
    {"$project": bson.M{"user.posts": 0}},
})
```