# MGO Pipe with $lookup query won't attach matching documents from "joined" collection

Tags: go, struct, aggregation-framework, mgo

My Models

```golang
type (
    //Category implements item category in database
    Category struct {
        ID          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id"`
        Name        string        `bson:"name" json:"name" form:"name" valid:"Required"`
        IsActive    bool          `bson:"is_active" json:"is_active" form:"is_active" valid:"Required"`
        Slug        string        `bson:"slug" json:"slug"`
        Icon        string        `bson:"icon" json:"icon" form:"icon"`
        SidebarIcon string        `bson:"sidebar_icon" json:"sidebar_icon" form:"sidebar_icon"`
        Parent      bson.ObjectId `bson:"parent,omitempty" json:"parent,omitempty" form:"parent"`
        CreatedAt   time.Time     `bson:"created_at" json:"-"`
        UpdatedAt   time.Time     `bson:"updated_at" json:"-"`
        IsDeleted   bool          `bson:"is_deleted" json:"-"`
    }
)
```

My get collection query:

```golang
categories := []models.Category{}

f := func(collection *mgo.Collection) error {
        query := []bson.M{
            {
                "$match": bson.M{
                    "is_deleted": bson.M{
                        "$ne": true,
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                "$sort": bson.M{
                    orderBy: pipeOrder,
                },
            },
            {
                "$limit": limit,
            },
            {
                "$skip": skip,
            },
            {
                "$lookup": bson.M{
                    "from":         "categories",
                    "localField":   "_id",
                    "foreignField": "parent",
                    "as":           "parentlist",
                },
            },
        }

        return collection.Pipe(query).All(&categories)
```

**Goal** : retrieve all the category along with their parent if their parent id matches with one of the document inside the collection.

**Issue** : retrieved all the category but missing 'parentlist' joined attribute

**Stack** : mgo to interact with DB and golang version 1.8

Comment: You unmarshal into `categories`: `All(&categories)`. What is `categories`?

Comment: @icza categories is an array that will store all the documents that i get from my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your aggregation you lookup the parents and they will be stored in a field called `parentlist`. And you try to unmarshal the results into a slice of `Category`, but the type `Category` has no field that would match `parentlist`. So that field will be "lost" during the unmarshaling process.

There are many ways to get the additional `parentlist`, some of the possibilities are detailed in this answer: [Mgo aggregation: how to reuse model types to query and unmarshal "mixed" results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774424/mgo-aggregation-how-to-reuse-model-types-to-query-and-unmarshal-mixed-results/46774425#46774425)

One option is to use a wrapper struct like this:

```
type CategoryWithParents struct {
    Category models.Category    `bson:",inline"`
    Parents  []*models.Category `bson:"parentlist"`
}
```

And unmarshal into a slice of this:

```
var results []CategoryWithParents

err := collection.Pipe(query).All(&results)
```

This will get all the parents.

If there may be one parent at most for all categories, you can modify the aggregation to `$unwind` the `parentlist`, and `Parents` may be a single `*model.Category` instead of a slice:

```
type CategoryWithParents struct {
    Category       models.Category  `bson:",inline"`
    OptionalParent *models.Category `bson:"parentlist"`
}

var results []CategoryWithParents

f := func(collection *mgo.Collection) error {
    query := []bson.M{
        {
            "$match": bson.M{
                "is_deleted": bson.M{
                    "$ne": true,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            "$sort": bson.M{
                orderBy: pipeOrder,
            },
        },
        {"$limit": limit},
        {"$skip": skip},
        {
            "$lookup": bson.M{
                "from":         "categories",
                "localField":   "_id",
                "foreignField": "parent",
                "as":           "parentlist",
            },
        },
        {
            "$unwind": bson.M{
                "path":                       "parentlist",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true,
            },
        },
    }

    return collection.Pipe(query).All(&results)
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you did not use embedding here?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg No particular reason. It works with both regular and embedded field. What matters is the `,inline` bson tag option.