# Google App Engine Datastore returns no rows if i have an Order clause

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a 'kind' in datastore like so:

```
type CompanyDS struct {
    Name string
}
```

If i query it with the 'order' clause below, it returns no rows (but doesn't give any error):

```
var companiesDS []CompanyDS
datastore.NewQuery("Company").Order("Name").GetAll(c, &companiesDS)
```

However if i remove the 'order("Name")' section it returns all the rows just fine.

Comment: It's been a while since I used GAE, but do you need index for Name field?

Comment: @realharry It doesn't auto-generate an index on the Name field in the index.yaml file, so i tried adding a manual one, but it gives an error stating "This index is not necessary, since single-property indexes are built in. Please remove it from your index file" so it seems like my indexes are already as they should be.

Comment: you are right, a single field indexes are all automatically built, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Will that make a difference if you do `datastore.NewQuery("Company").GetAll(c, &companiesDS).Order("Name")`?

Comment: Please check your entities in the datastore, they most likely have a lowercased `"name"` property. If so, use `.Order("name")` accordingly.

Comment: @icza I checked, it's already uppercase, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @realharry I tried that, but it doesn't compile, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: `Query.GetAll()` returns a slice of keys and an error. Please check that error (and the returned keys slice).

Comment: @icza I check the error and it's nil, which isn't helpful. I assume the keys are the same length as companiesDS eg zero, although i only look at companiesDS.

Comment: What happens if you run the following GQL in the Google Cloud Platform Datastore console: `select * from Compay order by Name`? Do you see the results? (You should if entities with `Name` property exist.)

Comment: @icza Great suggestion! I tried that. `select * from Company` returns rows, whereas `select * from Company order by Name` returns "No entities matched this query."

Comment: @Chris Then most likely your existing entities were saved explicitly with `Name` property being non-indexed. If this is the case and you do need index on `Name`, you have to load all entities (e.g. without `Order()`), then re-save all entities (without modification), so the `Name` property gets indexed. After that you'll be able to query them using `Order("Name")`. And make sure the code that saves them does not "disable" indexing on `Name`.

Comment: When on the Datastore consol you execute the `select * from Company`, you see the results. click on one, then you will see which properties are indexed. Please confirm if `Name` property is indexed.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was reading here and came to the same conclusion as you: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#unindexed_properties

Comment: Feel free to post your suggestion as an answer instead of comment so i can  vote as correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since without `Order()` you can query all entities, that means they do exist with name `"Company"` and property `"Name"`.

Indices for single properties are automatically created, so you don't need to specify explicit index for them.

But if you can't list them using a single property ordering like `Order("Name")`, that means that your existing entities are not indexed with the `Name` property. Note that every single entity may be indexed differently. When you save (put) an entity into the Datastore, you have the ability to specify which properties are to be indexed and which are not.

You can confirm this on the  Google Cloud Platform Datastore console: execute the query

```
select * from Company
```

Then click on any of the results (its ID), then you will see the details of that entity, listing which property is indexed and which is not.

#### Fix:

You may edit the entities on the console: click on the "Name" property, and before saving, check the "Index this property". This will re-save this entity, making its `Name` indexed, and thus it will show up in the next query (ordered by `Name`).

You don't need to do this manually for all entities. Use your Go query code (without `Order()`), query all entities, then re-save all without modification, and so the `Name` will get indexed as a result of this (because your `CompanyDS` does not turn off indexing for the `Name` property). Make sure your struct contains all properties, else you would lose them when re-saving.

**Note:** You should ensure that the code that saves `Company` entities saves them with `Name` indexed.

In Go for example a [struct tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) with value `",noindex"` will disable indexing for a single property like in this example:

```
type CompanyDS struct {
    Name string `datastore:",noindex"`
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to edit my entities in the google cloud platform console, and tick the box 'Index this property' in the Name field.