# Datastore query returns no data when ordering result

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple test object Foo with the string property Bar. When I do a .GetAll("Foo") query I get all objects returned, however, when I add .Order("Bar") then nothing is returned. I have tried both with and without index.yaml specifying the object and property, with and without sort order. What am I missing? I'm not using "noindex" on the Bar property.

```
type Foo struct {
   Bar string
}

.NewQuery("Foo").Order("Bar").GetAll(c, &foo)  <-- nothing returned

.NewQuery("Foo").GetAll(c, &foo)  <-- objects returned
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine Datastore returns no rows if i have an Order clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446523/google-app-engine-datastore-returns-no-rows-if-i-have-an-order-clause/47455578#47455578).

Comment: Please add code for your Foo struct and for insert (put) and query.

Comment: @icza I'm doing it exactly like that. There are no "noindex" properties. I'm running everything locally, and even if I start with a blank datastore, add 1 or multiple records, I still can't get any records returned with .Order() specified.

Answer (score 1):

Entities are indexed at the moment of inserting.

1. Make sure your struct field does not have `noindex` annotation for datastore.
2. Make sure your struct field does not change property name in the annotation (comment. e.g.:

   Bar string // `datastore:bar`
3. Make sure you did not override PropertyLoadSaver and do not make the property unindexable and do not change name.
4. Check in datastore viewer you can order on the property so it's not problem with your Put() code and probably problem with your query.