# Missing function body and string tag in struct

Tags: function, elasticsearch, go, struct, syntax

I find some function with no function body in Go. I know it means external function in Go. But where can I find the function boby?

```
type Creator func(*Beat, *common.Config) (Beater, error)
```

I also find a string in Go struct. What does it mean?

```
type BeatConfig struct {
    // output/publishing related configurations
    Output common.ConfigNamespace `config:"output"`
}
```

All of the above code can be found in elasticsearch beats:
https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/libbeat/beat/beat.go

Comment: Duplicate, both.

Comment: @Adrian Not a duplicate as this is not a function declaration but a type declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
type Creator func(*Beat, *common.Config) (Beater, error)
```

Is not a [function declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations), it's a [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations). It creates a new type (with a function type as its [underlying](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) type), it does not declare any functions, and so no function body is required, it wouldn't make sense and you cannot provide a body in there.

You can use it for example to create a variable of that type, and store an actual function value which has the same underlying type.

Example:

```
type Creator func(*Beat, *common.Config) (Beater, error)

func SomeCreator(beat *Beat, config *common.Config) (Beater, error) {
    // Do something
    return nil, nil
}

func main() {
    var mycreator Creator = SomeCreator
    // call it:
    beater, err := mycreator(&Beat{}, &common.Config{})
    // check err, use beater
}
```

And this field declaration:

```
Output common.ConfigNamespace `config:"output"`
```

Contains a [tag declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) for the `Output` field. For more details, see [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and easy to understand, I now understand! ! And it made me aware of my own carelessness. Thanks again! !

Answer (score 0):

As @icza said, `Creator` is a [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations).

In your case, each implementation of `Beat` has implemented `Creator` interface. Here is [beats's document](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/0cacffef95674632cc2b1039376210716733b2c2/libbeat/cmd/instance/doc.go#L7-L9).

Comment: thans for your supplement !!