# Understanding the Logic of Kubernetes API framework in Go

Tags: rest, api, go, kubernetes

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around learning Go, some details of the kubernetes API I haven't used before and the kubernetes api framework for Go at the same time, and would appreciate your help in understanding the grammar of that framework and why people use it anyways.

Honestly I'm not sure why to use a framework in the first place if it contains the same information as the REST endpoint. Wouldn't it make more sense to just call the API directly via a `http` library?

And here's one example (taken from [some real code](https://github.com/coreos/etcd-operator/blob/master/cmd/operator/main.go#L171)):

```
pod, err := kubecli.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).Get(name, metav1.GetOptions{})
```

What I feel bothersome is that I have to [look up everything in the API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/) and then I additionally need to figure out that `/v1/` translates to `CoreV1()`. And I'm not even sure where I could look that up. Also the whole block `metav1.GetOptions{}` seems completely unnecessary, or which part of a HTTP request is represented by it?

I hope I could make clear what the confusion is and hope for your help in clearing it up.

### Edit:

Here's also an example, generated from the new operator-framework which sadly doesn't make it much better:

```
 return &v1.Pod{
    TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       "Pod",
            APIVersion: "v1",
    },
    ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      "busy-box",
            Namespace: cr.Namespace,
            OwnerReferences: []metav1.OwnerReference{
                    *metav1.NewControllerRef(cr, schema.GroupVersionKind{
                            Group:   v1alpha1.SchemeGroupVersion.Group,
                            Version: v1alpha1.SchemeGroupVersion.Version,
                            Kind:    "Memcached",
                    }),
            },
            Labels: labels,
    },
    Spec: v1.PodSpec{
            Containers: []v1.Container{
                    {
                            Name:    "busybox",
                            Image:   "busybox",
                            Command: []string{"sleep", "3600"},
                    },
            },
    },
 }
```

The [API docs](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.9/#pod-v1-core) don't know anything about this `TypeMeta` object. And the second element is called `ObjectMeta:` instead of `metadata`. I mean, I'm not a magician. How should I know this.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do maybe the REST endpoint makes sense. However if you need to easily manipulate the api objects that get returned in Go then using the client is surely the best solution?

Comment: But how do you find out about which is the object you want to manipulate? E.g. how do you find out about `CoreV1` being called `CoreV1` instead of `v1`? I wonder if most people use editors with code completion so they don't even know about this pain point.

Comment: As good and as popular as k8s is I don't know if the kubecli package is a good example of idiomatic Go. In particular creating chainable methods like that is a recipe for lines of code that are really long and hard to read and reason about in context. It seems like it's written deliberately to match the CLI syntax. Which cuts down on the cognitive load if you're translating between cli commands and Go but not if you're trying to learn Go.

Comment: @voutasaurus The point is not learning Go. The point is learning to write Go code that talks to the API. That I'm not an expert at Go is just a hint for someone who knows how to do this, so they can think about ways that a non-Go-coder might not consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but here is my 2 cents.

## Why to use `client-go` instead of `http` library

There are serval pros with `client-go`.

1. Kubernetes resource is defined as **strongly-typed class**, means less misspelled debugging and easy to refactor.
2. When we manipulate some resources, It **authenticates with cluster automatically** ([doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/examples)), what it only needs is a valid config. And we need not to know how exactly the authentication is done.
3. It has multiple versions **compatible** with different Kubernetes version. It make our code align with specify kubernetes version much easier, without knowing every detail of API changes.

## How do I know which class and method should be called

In [API Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/), each resource has the latest Group and Version tag. 
For example, [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#pod-v1-core) is group `core`, version `v1`, kind `Pod` in v1.10.

[GoDoc](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes) listed all properties and links to detail explanation for every class like [Pod](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#Pod).

So the pod list can be found by calling [`CoreV1()`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes#Clientset.CoreV1), then [`Pods(namespace string)`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#PodsGetter), then [`List(opts meta_v1.ListOptions)`](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#PodInterface).

Comment: Honestly haven't expected anymore to get such a good explanation, but that's exactly what I was looking for. Some sweet resource saving support like covering multiple kubernetes api versions with the same code block, well formatted, and an example. Thanks for showing that the true stackoverflow still exists!

Answer (score 1):

A colleague suggested that there are in fact autogenerated docs called [godoc](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/core/v1#Pod). While it doesn't answer all questions it's improving my ability to to use the API libraries already.

Comment: For reading the code blocks it is also interesting to know what struct [metadata is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a couple of things to what's been mentioned so far:

You could indeed simply make http calls against the apiserver but `client-go` has already done all the hard work for you! Take for example this 'watch' endpoint:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#watch-202

you could code up the functionality yourself, or make use of e.g. the `SharedInformer` interface

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/tools/cache/shared_informer.go#L34-L41

The code in client-go has been tested and should be relatively bug-free.

If you set up your editor correctly for golang it will give you type hints and available function calls when you start typing in golang API calls.

I'd first learn golang and then try to grok `client-go`