# Empty fields while doing json unmarshal

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have written this piece of code. I can't figure out why it is giving empty fields when i run it. I have tried Uppercase variables. Still doesn't work.

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
)

type FirstName struct {
        Name1 string
}
type SecondName struct {
        Name2 string
}
type Person struct {
        Details     FirstName
        MoreDetails SecondName
}

func main() {
        var someGuy Person
        var data = []byte(`{"details": {"firstName": "alan"}, "moreDetails": {"surName": "Turing"}}`)
        json.Unmarshal(data, &someGuy)
        fmt.Println(someGuy)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JSON to Go mapping is incorrect. To have automatic matching between struct fields and the JSON properties during the unmarshaling process, the field *names* (and not the name of their types) must match the properties in JSON (in a case in-sensitive manner):

```
type FirstName struct {
    FirstName string
}
type SecondName struct {
    SurName string
}
type Person struct {
    Details     FirstName
    MoreDetails SecondName
}
```

With this, the output is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tf5qU3mT8Jx)):

```
{{alan} {Turing}}
```

If you want to keep those names in Go, another option is to provide a *mapping* between Go struct fields and JSON property names. For this you may use [struct tags](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

```
type FirstName struct {
    Name1 string `json:"firstName"`
}
type SecondName struct {
    Name2 string `json:"surName"`
}
```

Output will be the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/nCZ7rBjpBjy).

For an introduction and more details about struct tags, see [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)