# Golang variable declaration syntax meaning

Tags: go

I am going through some Golang code and came through this block of code, I am not able to comprehend it. I can see that d1,d2,d3 are variables of type int. But what is the last string `json:"start"`

```
type obj1 struct {
    d1   int `json:"start"`
    d2     int `json:"end"`
    d3 int   `json:"retries"`
}
```

Comment: The `\`json:"start"\`` portion means that when Unmarshaling/Marshaling, the field `d1`, for example, corresponds with the JSON key `start`

Comment: Also see: [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373)

Answer (score 1):

`d1`, `d2`, and `d3` are not variables, they are struct fields. The string is a "struct tag".

This is all described in the [Struct Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) documentation in the language spec.

Comment: Would the term `attributes` be acceptable too?

Comment: @Derek: the language refers to them as fields, and the word "attribute" doesn't quite have the same meaning. You could say the tag becomes an attribute of the field however.

Comment: thanks, its a tad tedious to try to keep all the technical jargon straight, especially when going from PHP to JavaScript and GO all day