# What are the locationName tags and how can they be used?

Tags: go, tags, aws-sdk

I was going over the go SDK for aws ec2.
I don't understand why almost all the structs in the SDK have this tag :`locationName'

For Example 
type DescribeInstancesOutput struct {

```
// The token to use to retrieve the next page of results. This value is null
// when there are no more results to return.
NextToken *string `locationName:"nextToken" type:"string"`

// Zero or more reservations.
Reservations []*Reservation `***locationName***:"reservationSet" locationNameList:"item" type:"list"`
// contains filtered or unexported fields
```

}
Does anyone know the purpose of the tags?

Source - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ec2/#DescribeInstancesOutput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [searching the source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/search?q=structtag.Get%28%22locationname%22%29&unscoped_q=structtag.Get%28%22locationname%22%29), it appears it's used with internal json/xml parsing/encoding. This is similar to the way that the `json` tag is used by [`encoding/json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30889373/4884579) answer goes into pretty good depth on tags in go.

They can be accessed/used with the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag) package.

Comment: perfect. this source is put in a private package and I think the users don't have to worry about those tags. they are there just for (um)marshaling purposes within the sdk.