# How to filter fields from a mongo document with the official mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, projection, mongo-go

How can I filter fields with the mongo-go-driver. 
Tried it with findopt.Projection but no success.

```
type fields struct {
    _id int16
}

s := bson.NewDocument()
filter := bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.ObjectID("_id", starterId))

var opts []findopt.One
opts = append(opts, findopt.Projection(fields{
    _id: 0,
}))

staCon.collection.FindOne(nil, filter, opts...).Decode(s)
```

In the end, I want to suppress the field "_id". But the documents didn't change.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit:** As the mongo-go driver evolved, it is possible to specify a projection using a simple [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#M) like this:

```
options.FindOne().SetProjection(bson.M{"_id": 0})
```

Original (old) answer follows.

---

The reason why it doesn't work for you is because the field `fields._id` is unexported, and as such, no other package can access it (only the declaring package).

You must use a field name that is exported (starts with an uppercase latter), e.g. `ID`, and use [struct tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to map it to the MongoDB `_id` field like this:

```
type fields struct {
    ID int `bson:"_id"`
}
```

And now to perform a query using a projection:

```
projection := fields{
    ID: 0,
}
result := staCon.collection.FindOne(
    nil, filter, options.FindOne().SetProjection(projection)).Decode(s)
```

Note that you may also use a [`bson.Document`](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#Document) as the projection, you don't need your own struct type. E.g. the following does the same:

```
projection := bson.NewDocument(
    bson.EC.Int32("_id", 0),
)
result := staCon.collection.FindOne(
    nil, filter, options.FindOne().SetProjection(projection)).Decode(s)
```

Comment: well that's too complicated, is i really need to define a struct ?, or i can use bson.M ?

Comment: @LoboNokeweNgewe Yes, you may also use a `bson.M` value. Since this answer was created, the mongo-go driver improved a lot.

Comment: Fo multiple projection fields use `bson.D{{"_id", 0}, {"name", 1}}`