# what are the uses of semantic comments in Go?

Tags: go

By analogy with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) about tags I note that there are several uses of comments in go beyond pure commentary.

Examples:

- [go:generate](https://blog.golang.org/generate) can be used for code generation.
- [godoc](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) uses the function name to indicate comments it should interpret
- [build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) constraints

Are there any others I've missed?

Is there a definitive list somewhere?

Some third party packages like [gocontracts](https://github.com/Parquery/gocontracts) and [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger) use them as well. How can they avoid conflicting with each other?

Comment: See also https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9522973

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking import path checking comment

Comment: @vearutop good spot I should probably make this a community wiki

Comment: https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#false-positives ignore lint false positive (3rd party)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted [comments are directives in go](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9522973) not just comments.

There is at the time of writing no definitive list. 
This as logged as an [golang issue 28532](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28532).

Therefore I propose using this answer to make one.

Uses in the go core language and tools themselves:

- [go:generate](https://blog.golang.org/generate) can be used for code generation.
- [godoc](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code) uses the function name to indicate comments it should interpret
- [Examples](https://blog.golang.org/examples) - document the expected output of a test (thanks @Butuzov)
- [build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) constraints (starting with '*// +build*')
- [Import comments](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_checking) e.g. '*package math // import "path"*'

Notable uses in third party packages

- [gocontracts](https://github.com/Parquery/gocontracts) - specify preconditions as comments
- [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger) - document a ReST API using swagger
- [golangci](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#false-positives) e.g. //nolint[:linter1,linter2,...]

How can they avoid conflicting with each other?

If you are developing a tool that really needs to treat comments as attributes and wish to avoid conflict with other similar uses prefix your comments with a namespace like "*{mytool}*: "

There are some conscious attempts at namespacing.
Magic comments built into go use the "go: " prefix as in "go:generate"
(except where they don't)

go-swagger uses "swagger: "

However you still need to approach this with caution and check the list here or any other source you can find.

Also consider whether comments are the best [or only](https://github.com/Parquery/gocontracts/issues/22) approach rather than using functions instead.
Compare for instance ([gocontracts](https://github.com/Parquery/gocontracts)):

```
// SomeFunc ensures:
//  * !strings.HasSuffix(result, "smth")
func SomeFunc(x int) (result string) {
    // ...
}
```

with ([godbc](https://godoc.org/github.com/lpabon/godbc))

```
func SomeFunc(x int) (result string) {
    godbc.Require(strings.HasSuffix(result,"smth");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Examples](https://blog.golang.org/examples) - Allow to test function for `example` output.

Copy/Paste from link above.

```
package stringutil_test

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/golang/example/stringutil"
)

func ExampleReverse() {
    fmt.Println(stringutil.Reverse("hello"))
    // Output: olleh
}
```