# What is the best way in typescript to manage model instantiation and creation?

Tags: typescript

I've been struggling with the right way to instantiate and initialise a model in typescript. In my project I'm using nest where I get an object via an API which is validated by casting it to a DTO, the DTO should then be used to create an instance of the model.

I believe the standard way would be like this:

```
class myModel {
   public constructor (public property: string) {
   }
}

class MyModelDto {
    public property: string;
}

// instantiation function, the input would come from an http post body:
public function createMyModel(bodyData: MyModelDto) {
      const myModel = new MyModel(bodyData.property);
}
```

The upside is that it will never create a myModel instantiation with the wrong properties, since they are all required and you can't pass extra properties to the model. 
The problem however is that you have to add the full list with each instantiation of your model. This is fine with a few properties, but gets a bit tedious as soon as you introduce multiple (10+). Also because the order matters, you run the risk of inputting the wrong data into the wrong property. As long as the types are the same, your compiler won't complain.

So an alternative to this would be:

```
class myModel {
   public property: string

   public constructor (data: myModelInterface) {
      Object.assign(this, data)
   }
}

interface myModelInterface {
  property: string;
}

class MyModelDto {
    public property: string;
}

// instantiation function, the input would come from an http post body:
public function createMyModel(bodyData: MyModelDto) {
      const myModel = new MyModel(bodyData);
}
```

This is already a lot cleaner on the instantiation. Even though you have to have the same list of properties twice (model & interface) you will never have more than 2. 
This would have my preference, but the downside of this, is that the compiler will only tell you that bodyData is wrong if you OMIT properties from the MyModelDto definition, but if you add extra properties, it will not complain, nor will it omit the data in your `const myModel`. Effectively negating a lot of the typescript benefits.

It would be nice if `Obect.assign` only takes the properties specified in the `MyModel` class, or if the myModel interface would complain on any difference between the input and the interface, rather than just on a property not being there. But I don't think that is how javascript works.

I have tried some other options (creating my own version of Object.assign), but nothing I have found is a clean way to implement this. I am a little surprised that something that is this basic doesn't seem to have a clearcut solution. (but maybe I am just being naive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have to convert between two different representation for some data I first create an interface using generics that represents a mapper between the two representations:

```
export interface IMapper<T, R> {
    toDTO(model: T): R;

    toModel(dto: R): T;
}
```

Then in the implementation of the method toDTO and toModel I manage the mapping of informations between the two classes:

```
class MyMapper implements IMapper<MyModel, MyModelDTO> {
    public toDTO(model: MyModel) {
        let dto = new MyModelDTO(....);
        // map model infos to dto
        ....
        returFor the convertion sometimes I n dto;
    }
    public toModel(dto: MyModelDTO) {
        let model = new MyModel(....);
        // map dto infos to model
        ....
        return model;
    }
}
```

The convertion is different case by case.

Sometimes it can be something simple like:

```
for (let prop in model) {
  if (dto[prop]) { 
    dto[prop] = model[prop] 
  }
}
```

In other cases I use a object to aide mapping properties of model to those of dto eg:

```
class MyMapper implements IMapper<MyModel, MyModelDTO> {
    private readonly modelToDto = {foo: 'property1', bar: 'prop2'};

    public toDTO(model: MyModel) {
        let dto = new MyModelDTO(....);
        Object.keys(this.fields).forEach((k) => {
            dto[this.fields[k]] = model[k];
        });

        return dto
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I understand that this works, but it means creating something that I feel should not be necessary. However I understand from the lack of response that their is no clear TS intended way of doing this.

Comment: Yes. having something like go tags would be great. But I haven't find anything similar yet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30889373/121199 to see what tags  can do