# Go struct tag throwing error: "field tag must be a string"

Tags: go

I'm using GO for the first time and am setting up a little example API. In trying to return a JSON object from a struct that I made, I get this error when I add a struct tag to my fields:

"field tag must be a string" and "invalid character literal (more than one character)".

Here's my code breakdown. What am I missing here?

```
    package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/demo/v1/version", getVersion).Methods("GET")    
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))    
}


func getVersion(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    version := Version{ID: "demo", Version: "1.0.0", Sha: "some hash...."}
    var myJSON, err = json.Marshal(version)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(myJSON)

}

type Version struct {
    //ERRORS on these 3 lines:
    ID      string 'json:"id"'
    Version string 'json:"version, omitempty"'
    Sha     string 'json:"sha"'
}
```

Comment: The code use the quote character for rune literals.  Use one of the quote characters for string instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your struct tags with *back quotes* instead of using single quotes to create raw string literals which can allow for the inclusion of additional data in the tag field.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go) post gives a good explanation of tags, how they are constructed properly and should serve as a good reference for further explanation if needed.

Working code here:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Version struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Version string `json:"version, omitempty"`
    Sha     string `json:"sha"`
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/demo/v1/version", getVersion).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}

func getVersion(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    version := Version{ID: "demo", Version: "1.0.0", Sha: "some hash...."}
    var myJSON, err = json.Marshal(version)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(myJSON)
}
```

Comment: Ah! *facepalm* It's backticks, not single quotes. Even after all these years I still run into the "missing a semicolon" type errors ...

Comment: A linter usually helps me catch things like this. [Here](https://github.com/golangci/awesome-go-linters) is a list of go linters for your consideration