# Golang get struct's field name by JSON tag

Tags: go

I have a struct:

```
type Human struct {
    Head  string  `json:"a1"`
    Body  string  `json:"a2"`
    Leg   string  `json:"a3"`
}
```

How can I get the struct's field name by providing JSON tag name? Probably something like this:

```
fmt.Println(getFieldName("a1")) // "Head"
fmt.Println(getFieldName("a2")) // "Body"
fmt.Println(getFieldName("a99")) // ""

func getFieldName(tag string) (fieldname string) {
    /* ... */
}
```

How should I implement the `getFieldName` function? I read online, it seems I need to use the `reflect` package, hmmm... any helping hand? :)

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#example_StructTag

Comment: the example shows "json" -> "a1", but I want do it backwards, such as "a1" -> "Head"... hmmm, I try to read the documentation again... thanks...

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/8X64XBwh03o

Comment: Range over the fields until you find the one with the tag you're looking for. [What are the use(s) for tags in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) If you need this frequently, build a map, mapping from tag to field, so future lookups become a single map indexing.

Comment: wow... thanks... I keep thinking for a direct lookup approach, but can't find any. Haven't think for using the `for loop` to retrieve the field name... Haha. Thanks for helping...

Comment: @mkopriva: great answer  - why not post it as an answer instead of comment? Otherwise the question still appears in Unanswered

Comment: @EliBendersky answer added.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `reflect` package to loop over a struct's fields and match against their tag values.

```
func getFieldName(tag, key string, s interface{}) (fieldname string) {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    if rt.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("bad type")
    }
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        f := rt.Field(i)
        v := strings.Split(f.Tag.Get(key), ",")[0] // use split to ignore tag "options" like omitempty, etc.
        if v == tag {
            return f.Name
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/2zCC7pZKJTz

---

Alternatively, as pointed out by @icza, you can build up a map and then use that for quicker lookups.

```
//                         Human            json       a1     Head
var fieldsByTag = make(map[reflect.Type]map[string]map[string]string)

func buildFieldsByTagMap(key string, s interface{}) {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    if rt.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        panic("bad type")
    }

    if fieldsByTag[rt] == nil {
        fieldsByTag[rt] = make(map[string]map[string]string)
    }
    if fieldsByTag[rt][key] == nil {
        fieldsByTag[rt][key] = make(map[string]string)
    }

    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        f := rt.Field(i)
        v := strings.Split(f.Tag.Get(key), ",")[0] // use split to ignore tag "options"
        if v == "" || v == "-" {
            continue
        }
        fieldsByTag[rt][key][v] = f.Name
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/qlt_mWsXGju

Answer (score 1):

I worked over other solutions and developed my `get boolean field value from json tag value`. You can change it according to your scenario easily.

```
func GetBooleanFieldValueByJsonTag(jsonTagValue string, s interface{}) bool {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(s)
    if rt.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return false
    }
    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        f := rt.Field(i)
        v := strings.Split(f.Tag.Get("json"), ",")[0] // use split to ignore tag "options" like omitempty, etc.
        if v == jsonTagValue {
            r := reflect.ValueOf(s)
            field := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(f.Name)
            return field.Bool()
        }
    }
    return false
}
```