# How to run a query with Boolean property check

Tags: database, mongodb, go, mgo

**Folder documents:**

```
{"_id":"5d1e2da512ad38225af60869","id":1,"name":"inbox","must":true}
{"_id":"5d1e2da512ad38225af6086b","id":2,"name":"outbox","must":true}
{"_id":"5d1e2da512ad38225af6086d","id":3,"name":"drafts","must":true}
{"_id":"5d1e2da512ad38225af6086f","id":4,"name":"trash","must":true}
```

**Mail documents:**

```
{"_id":"5d1e2da512ad38225af60871","id":1,"isdeleted":true,"foldersids":[1],"subject":"Hello1","body":"Hello this is mail 1"}
{"_id":"5d1e2da512ad38225af60873","id":2,"isdeleted":false,"foldersids":[1],"subject":"Hello2","body":"Hello this is mail 2"}
```

I'm trying to get all the mails that are not marked as deleted, and get their Id value only, which is a separate field (not object_id field)

In my database I have 2 documents - 1 marked as deleted and 1 marked as not deleted. This code always returns both of the documents although the expected result is that it returns only the I'd of the one that is not deleted. What could cause it to fail?

Edit: Complete example

**My golang code**:

**Folder.go**

```
package main

type Folder struct {
    Id int
    Name string
    Must bool
}
```

**Mail.go**

```
package main

type Mail struct{
    Id int
    IsDeleted bool
    FoldersIds []int
    Subject string
    Body string
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/globalsign/mgo"
    "github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson"
)

func main(){
    inbox := Folder{
        Id:1,
        Name:"inbox",
        Must:true,
    }
    outbox := Folder{
        Id:2,
        Name:"outbox",
        Must:true,
    }
    drafts := Folder{
        Id:3,
        Name:"drafts",
        Must:true,
    }
    trash := Folder{
        Id:4,
        Name:"trash",
        Must:true,
    }

    session, _ := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")

    session.DB("Outlook").C("Folders").Upsert(bson.M{"id": inbox.Id}, inbox)
    session.DB("Outlook").C("Folders").Upsert(bson.M{"id": outbox.Id}, outbox)
    session.DB("Outlook").C("Folders").Upsert(bson.M{"id": drafts.Id}, drafts)
    session.DB("Outlook").C("Folders").Upsert(bson.M{"id": trash.Id}, trash)

    mail1 := Mail{Id:1,Body:"Hello this is mail 1", FoldersIds:[]int{1}, IsDeleted:true, Subject:"Hello1"}
    mail2 := Mail{Id:2,Body:"Hello this is mail 2", FoldersIds:[]int{1}, IsDeleted:false, Subject:"Hello2"}

    session.DB("Outlook").C("Mails").Upsert(bson.M{"id": 1}, mail1)
    session.DB("Outlook").C("Mails").Upsert(bson.M{"id": 2}, mail2)

    var mails []Mail

    session.DB("Outlook").C("Mails").Find(bson.M{"IsDeleted": bson.M{"$ne": true}}).Select(bson.M{"Id": 1}).All(&mails)

    fmt.Println(len(mails)) // Why is this 2 and not 1?????
}
```

Comment: Please post your documents in MongoDB. The output of `db.mails.find()`.

Comment: @icza I produced a simple example here, hopefully it contains all the needed details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names of MongoDB document fields are case-sensitive. Your documents in the database have lowercased field names, e.g. `isdeleted` and `id`. So you must write the same when constructing your filter:

```
session.DB("Outlook").C("Mails").Find(bson.M{
    "isdeleted": bson.M{"$ne": true},
}).Select(bson.M{"id": 1}).All(&mails)
```

If you want to change how the names are saved in database, use the `bson` [struct tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373), e.g.:

```
type Mail struct {
    Id         int    `bson:"Id"`
    IsDeleted  bool   `bson:"IsDeleted"`
    FoldersIds []int  `bson:"FolderIds"`
    Subject    string `bson:"Subject"`
    Body       string `bson:"Body"`
}
```

Usually [Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) is used for names that are comprised of multiple words:

```
type Mail struct {
    Id         int    `bson:"id"`
    IsDeleted  bool   `bson:"isDeleted"`
    FoldersIds []int  `bson:"folderIDs"`
    Subject    string `bson:"subject"`
    Body       string `bson:"body"`
}
```

But you may use whatever naming strategy, all will work, but be consistent about it.